# Wireless not working - HP Probook 4540s

Tags: 12.04, wireless, ralink

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 on 3 HP Probook 4540s's, and none of them seems to be able to connect to wireless networks.

I have 1 Probook 4540s with Windows 7 installed and I can access wlan from it. I tried installing the necessary drivers from HP's website, but it still doesn't seem to be working.

I've seen other people with different Probooks having similar problems, but their computers seem to be able to detect and even attempt to connect wlans, while mine doesn't even acknowledge that it has wireless.

[image]

output from `sudo make`:

```
make -C tools
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/tools'
gcc -g bin2h.c -o bin2h
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/tools'
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/tools/bin2h
cp -f os/linux/Makefile.6 /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/Makefile
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-34-generic/build SUBDIRS=/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-34-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/crypt_md5.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/crypt_sha2.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/crypt_hmac.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.o
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c: In function ‘AES_Key_Wrap’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c:1466:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c: In function ‘AES_Key_Unwrap’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/crypt_aes.c:1561:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/crypt_arc4.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/mlme.o
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/mlme.c: In function ‘MlmeResetRalinkCounters’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/mlme.c:528:3: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/mlme.c:528:3: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_wep.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/action.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init_inf.o
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init_inf.c: In function ‘rt28xx_init’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init_inf.c:162:3: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_init_inf.c:178:10: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_tkip.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_aes.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_sync.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/eeprom.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_sanity.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_info.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_cfg.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_wpa.o
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_wpa.c: In function ‘PeerPairMsg3Action’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_wpa.c:1032:13: warning: unused variable ‘Cancelled’ [-Wunused-variable]
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_radar.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/spectrum.o
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/spectrum.c: In function ‘PeerMeasureReportAction’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/spectrum.c:1972:3: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_timer.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/rt_channel.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_profile.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_asic.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_cmd.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/ps.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/uapsd.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../rate_ctrl/ra_ctrl.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../rate_ctrl/alg_legacy.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../rate_ctrl/alg_ags.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rtmp_chip.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/assoc.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/auth.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/auth_rsp.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/sync.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/sanity.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.o
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.c: In function ‘STAHandleRxDataFrame’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.c:283:17: warning: unused variable ‘pFmeCtrl’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.c:282:8: warning: unused variable ‘OldPwrMgmt’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.c: In function ‘STAHandleRxMgmtFrame’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/rtmp_data.c:766:5: warning: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Wdeclaration-after-statement]
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/connect.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/wpa.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.o
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RTMPQueryInformation’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:3956:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘long unsigned int’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c: In function ‘RtmpIoctl_rt_private_get_statistics’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:7220:1: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 3 has type ‘EEPROM_NIC_CONFIG3_STRUC’ [-Wformat]
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/rt_os_util.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/ba_action.o
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/ba_action.c: In function ‘convert_reordering_packet_to_preAMSDU_or_802_3_packet’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/ba_action.c:1550:2: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/rt_led.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.o
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c: In function ‘RT28xxPciMlmeRadioOn’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_mac_pci.c:2245:13: warning: unused variable ‘Cancelled’ [-Wunused-variable]
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data_pci.o
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data_pci.c: In function ‘RTMPFreeTXDUponTxDmaDone’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data_pci.c:543:8: warning: unused variable ‘TXWISize’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data_pci.c: In function ‘RTMPHandleMgmtRingDmaDoneInterrupt’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/cmm_data_pci.c:738:8: warning: unused variable ‘TXWISize’ [-Wunused-variable]
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_mcu.o
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_mcu.c: In function ‘RtmpAsicSendCommandToMcu’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_mcu.c:464:8: warning: unused variable ‘offset’ [-Wunused-variable]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/rtmp_mcu.c:463:8: warning: unused variable ‘Configuration’ [-Wunused-variable]
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/ee_prom.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/ee_efuse.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/rt_rf.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt30xx.o
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.o
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c: In function ‘RT3290_AsicTxAlcGetAutoAgcOffset’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:1564:25: warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c: In function ‘MlmeAntSelection’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2489:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2489:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2489:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2507:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2522:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2522:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2523:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2523:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2526:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2526:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2527:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2527:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2528:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2528:5: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2545:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2545:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2545:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2559:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2565:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2574:8: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2581:8: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2583:7: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2583:7: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2595:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2595:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2596:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2596:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2597:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:2597:6: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c: In function ‘BtCoexSetting’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:3244:4: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘ULONG’ [-Wformat]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c: In function ‘Profile_TwoAnt’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../chips/rt3290.c:4097:2: warning: format ‘%x’ expects argument of type ‘unsigned int’, but argument 2 has type ‘CMB_CTRL_STRUC’ [-Wformat]
  CC [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/frq_cal.o
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/frq_cal.c: In function ‘FrequencyCalibration’:
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/frq_cal.c:198:18: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/frq_cal.c:211:18: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/frq_cal.c:227:18: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/frq_cal.c:252:18: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/frq_cal.c:265:18: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/frq_cal.c:281:18: warning: comparison of distinct pointer types lacks a cast [enabled by default]
/home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/../../common/frq_cal.c:132:10: warning: unused variable ‘bUpdateRFR’ [-Wunused-variable]
  LD [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/rt3290sta.o
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
WARNING: modpost: missing MODULE_LICENSE() in /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/rt3290sta.o
see include/linux/module.h for more information
  LD [M]  /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/rt3290sta.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-34-generic'
cp -f /home/olimp3/Downloads/Driver/Files/os/linux/rt3290sta.ko /tftpboot
```

output from `lspci -nnk | grep -EA3 Ralink`:

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:18ec]
04:00.1 Bluetooth [0d11]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:3298]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:18ec]
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168B PCI             Express Gigabit Ethernet controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:17f6]
```

Comment: I had EXACT same problem. let me help you out!

Comment: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6612/wireless-problems-help-room

Comment: Do you know which wireless card you have installed? If not run lspci in a terminal and paste the output.

Comment: @denNorske: I can't use chatrooms because of low rep.

Comment: Please provide the output of `lspci -nnk | grep -EA3 Ralink`. We'll need more information on your wireless device and this will provide numeric device identifiers.

Comment: added the output from lspci -nnk | grep -EA3 Ralink

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Ralink RT3290 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: **Download latest RT2860 driver source code from Ralink**

Go to http://www.ralinktech.com/

Click on Software
Click on Linux

Available since July 2010:

Download the driver 
`"RT2860PCI/mPCI/CB/PCIe(RT2760/RT2790/RT2860/RT2890)“` dated 07/16/2010, *version 2.4.0.0*
You need to enter a name and an email and press accept to download

Now, open a terminal by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, and type:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential dkms
cd Downloads/Driver
```

Now, to install it:

```
sudo make && sudo make install && sudo make clean
```

Then, when it finish:

Blacklist the built-in driver, and load the new one with:

```
echo "blacklist rt2800pci" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rt2800pci.conf
sudo modprobe -rfv rt2800pci
sudo modprobe -v rt3259sta
```

And reboot, and it should work!

Comment: After sudo modprobe -v rt3259sta I get the following error: FATAL: Module rt3259sta not found. I also get some stderr output from sudo make, which I added to the main text.