# Wireless Manager On A Rampage - Ranlink Driver RT3290 Active & In Use But Not Working

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers

I've just replaced Windows 8 on a HP Envy notebook with Ubuntu 12.04 and whereas before, the wireless LED on F12 would be blue to connect with wireless networks, it's now permanently red (not working) and in the Networks tab under System Settings, there is no reference to any sort of ability to connect to a wireless network - as well as wlan0 not existing when I type 'iwconfig' into the command line.

> stefanija@stefanija-HP-ENVY-Sleekbook-6-PC:~$ iwconfig
>
> lo        no wireless extensions.
>
> eth1      no wireless extensions.
>
> ra0       Ralink STA
>
> ```
>       Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
>
>       Rx invalid nwid:0  invalid crypt:0  invalid misc:0
> ```
>
> eth0      no wireless extensions

and

> stefanija@stefanija-HP-ENVY-Sleekbook-6-PC:~$ ifconfig wlan0 up wlan0:
>   ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device

I've researched similar issues and followed advice from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working) tutorial in order to make a suitable driver for RT3290. (as that's appropriate for my wireless card) I then rebooted and checked in the additional drivers to see if it had worked (as the computer still wasn't showing any wireless networks) and the driver was there, was active and in use, but still wasn't picking up any connections.

I also tried [this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/43752/how-to-install-a-wireless-card-in-linux-using-windows-drivers/) tutorial, however, I couldn't get past opening the file with the archive manager because the system hit an internal error and refused to extract it as an .exe.

I'd be extremely grateful if someone could tell me what happened or how I can fix this, and apologies if I haven't been very specific or posted this in the wrong place, or asked something stupid; I'm quite new to Ubuntu and the forums, heh, so if I've missed parts out or anything, please let me know.

Comment: Please add the result of the terminal command: rfkill list all

Comment: results of 'rfkill list all'
0: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no
1: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: wlan0 is not your wireless interface, ra0 is. I believe your device is included by default in Ubuntu 13.04. I suggest you upgrade.

Comment: I've updated, and Network Manager is still not showing any signs that a wireless option is available, eeep. Is there anything else I can try, do you think, please?

Comment: Let's have a look at: sudo modprobe rt2800pci and also: modinfo rt2800pci | grep 3290 and finally: dmesg | grep rt2. Thanks.

Comment: all three came up with no response, sowwie

_stefanija@stefanija-HP-ENVY-Sleekbook-6-PC:~$ sudo modprobe rt2800pci
[sudo] password for stefanija: 
root@stefanija-HP-ENVY-Sleekbook-6-PC:/home/stefanija# modprobe rt2800pci
root@stefanija-HP-ENVY-Sleekbook-6-PC:/home/stefanija# modinfo rt2800pci | grep 3290
root@stefanija-HP-ENVY-Sleekbook-6-PC:/home/stefanija# dmesg | grep rt2
root@stefanija-HP-ENVY-Sleekbook-6-PC:/home/stefanija#_

Comment: You upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04? Your device is included by default: alias:          pci:v00001814d00003290sv*sd*bc*sc*i* Please let us see: uname -r and also lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: I accidentally deleted a kernel (oops) and had to download and upgrade from 12.04 upwards again, but on upgrading to 13.04 again, it worked!
Thank you so, so much for your help, I really appreciate it! :D

Comment: The site loves to have answered questions and I love the reputation points, so let me convert this to an answer which you may accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your device is included by default in the driver rt2800pci in Ubuntu 13.04:

```
alias: pci:v00001814d00003290sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

Please upgrade to 13.04.