# WiFi not working in Ubuntu 13.10 with Ralink RT3290

Tags: wireless, 13.10

I have upgraded from Ubuntu 13.04 to Ubuntu 13.10 and now my WiFi doesn't work. It takes a lot of time to connect but when connected, connection is quickly lost again. In Ubuntu 13.04 worked fine.

Here are some outputs:

```
lspci | grep Wireless

01:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
```

---

```
sudo rfkill list

0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

---

```
lsmod | grep rt2800

rt2800pci              18966  0 
rt2800lib              95449  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00pci              13287  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             13661  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00lib              56053  4 rt2x00pci,rt2800lib,rt2800pci,rt2x00mmio
mac80211              634661  3 rt2x00lib,rt2x00pci,rt2800lib
eeprom_93cx6           13344  1 rt2800pci
crc_ccitt              12707  1 rt2800lib
```

---

```
dmesg | grep rt2800

[   19.959959] rt2800pci 0000:01:00.0: irq 46 for MSI/MSI-X
```

---

```
modinfo rt2800pci | grep 3290

alias:          pci:v00001814d00003290sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

**Solution for me:**

It appears a Ubuntu bug, I have found a solution here:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1049466

Post 117 and +

Thanks

Comment: This is all fine. Did you check that modinfo rt2800pci | grep 3290 gave you the output below?

Comment: I found [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working) for the same wireless card. The error happens with an older version of ubuntu (12.10 to 13.04) but it seems to be the same problem. Give it a try.

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: I have tried that answer and It fails when I do the make command. I have copied the terminal output here: http://pastebin.com/JeKm4n5J

Answer (score 1):

It should be working out of the box with the driver rt2800pci. On my system,

```
modinfo rt2800pci | grep 3290
alias:          pci:v00001814d00003290sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
```

which shows the correct Vendr and Product id, see this [Wikidevi page](http://wikidevi.com/wiki/Ralink_RT3290_Reference_Design). You should first check that you get the same output, then please proceed with these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo rmmod rt2800pci
sudo modprobe rt2800pci
```

This should take care of it.

Edit: please post the output of

```
sudo rfkill list
lsmod | grep rt2800
dmesg | grep rt2800
```

Edit: we may try to use the backport driver. You should issue these commands:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/10/18/backports-20131018.tar.gz 
tar xvfz backports-20131018.tar.gz
cd backports-20131018
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: I have done the commands and I have restarted my computer, but wifi doesn't work. The commands did not get me any output. Thank you

Comment: I have done these commands and reboot my pc but it is the same, the wifi don't get connection :(