# hp envy 15 wifi bug

Tags: wireless

I've recently bought a hp envy 15 notebook pc 15-j082sf, I installed ubuntu 13 on it and I can't get my wifi work, the wifi button stay orange and not white as it should be. I detect the wifi network but i can't connect to them i tried to do this `sudo rfkill list all` the result is that :

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hp-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hp-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I tried a lot of thing i found on the internet but i can't fix it any help please? 
what i tried : https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/233668

i found that if i type this

```
modprobe -r rt2800pci 
modprobe rt2800pci
```

the wifi work for like 10s then goes off again any idea

Comment: what it says when you give connect to a network? Include result of `dmesg | tail -n 20` just after you try connecting a network. Also post result of `lspci` , `sudo lshw -c network`

Comment: when i try to connect it just display a message saying disconnected you are now disconnected. the result of the commande are there : ( had to make it in pastebin since it was long ) http://pastebin.com/tPzJ5dBV

Comment: http://pastebin.com/g5AU4rZa updated

Comment: I see a couple of perturbing messages about some "serialmonkey.com". you sure you didn't do anything else. Edit your question and add everything you did, step by step after installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem fixed, I managed to make my wifi work doing this :

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2013/10/18/backports-20131018.tar.gz 
tar xvfz backports-20131018.tar.gz
cd backports-20131018
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

found the solution [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366610/wifi-not-working-in-ubuntu-13-10-with-ralink-rt3290) thanks for answering.

Answer (score 3):

just adding `blacklsit aser_wmi` to `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` worked in my case

Comment: This solution worked OK, but there is a type-o in the proposed line: it should say **"blacklist acer_wmi"**, with a C instead of an S. Cheers!