# Ralink 3290 not working again after upgrade to 13.10

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.10, ralink

When I installed ubuntu 13.04, and 12.10 on my current computer I lost the ability to use the RALINK 3290 wifi.  I was able, in the past, to get it working by following the advice posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working/253660#253660%5D).  But after upgrading to 13.10 I am once again stuck without wifi and the normal solution is not working.

Here is the problem in more detail. I obtain the Ralink 3290 driver from either the vendor or the dropbox folder as described, no problem.  I extract the folder and make changes as described if needed. I run the 'make' command, as the command is running I get several warnings and then when I try and 'make install'  I end up with error:2

Here is the output when I run "make" and "make install" - http://pastebin.com/jQ8dd0PQ

Clarification: My wifi is not totally non-fucntional, it can see the various wi-fi networks around me, and it tries to connect to my favorite ones, but it never fully connects.  It then just cycles through the various wifi networks, never connecting.

Comment: You  didn't do what is written at the end of [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/253660/6228). See extra guide. Do those steps, and it will compile fine. I tried this weekend

Comment: Yay! It's working, thanks @BЈовић.  I lost my mouse for a few mins after running those commands and rebooting, but the wifi worked.  After a rebooted a second time I got my mouse cursor back.