# How to access a folder through the terminal

Tags: command-line, software-installation

I'm trying to follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working) in getting my wireless to work. However I'm incredibly new at the whole Linux thing, and there is a part in there that I really just don't understand:

> Go to your main extracted folder (It should be the DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508 folder) and type the following:

```
make    
sudo make install
```

When he says "Go to", does he mean go to the file window? Wen I'm there and type "make" and hit Enter, it just opens up the file. How exactly am I supposed to make this thing work? What he is trying to say? I really just don't get it. Can somebody help me to understand this, so I can get my wireless working.

Answer (score 9):

**These should be done in the Terminal**

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>. This will open the Terminal.

> **Go To**: Means you should *access* the folder where the extracted file is in, *through* **Terminal**.

This cam be done with command,

```
cd [ dir ]
```

> **[ dir ]: Directory Path**
>
> To find the Directory Path,
>
> 1. **Right-Click** the *file*. **Right-Click** *Menu* will appear.
> 2. Then select the **Properties** *Option* in the **Right-Click** *Menu*
> 3. Then the **Properties** *Window* appear.
> 4. Go to the **Basic** *Tab* of it.
> 5. In the **Location** *field*, There is the Directory Path.
>
> Ex: /home/YOUR NAME/Downloads

So the command will be:

```
$ cd /home/YOUR NAME/Downloads
```

In order to paste the "file path" (i.e. /home/YOUR NAME/Downloads) into the terminal use CTRL + SHIFT + V (or right click in the terminal and paste click paste - don't forget to add the 'cd' at the start of the line).

***Other easy method that you can do is :***

> 1. In Terminal, type `cd` and make a space infrot
> 2. Then **Drag** and **Drop** the folder from the ***file browser*** to the ***Terminal***
> 3. Then Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Then you need to Enter `make` and `sudo make install` commands, one by one.

```
$ make

$ sudo make install
```

Answer (score 4):

- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.It will open gnome terminal,Then run the below commands to install **nautilus-open-terminal**.

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install nautilus-open-terminal
  nautilus -q
  ```

  Then close the terminal.
- Open the extracted folder `DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508`.Then `right-click` inside the `DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508` folder.There you find an option `open in terminal`,select it.

[image]

- A new terminal will open,in that terminal run the following commands,

  ```
  make
  sudo make install
  ```