# wifi scanning results say No scan results

Tags: wireless, networking, interface

I'm trying to use wifi access in Ubuntu 12.04 and for some reason, I do not want to use network-manager. So, I removed it.

What I'm trying to do is to see what kind of APs around me, so I issued the following command and results in:

```
$ sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
wlan0 No scan results
```

I'm pretty sure that I have lot of APs around me, and I'm not sure that my device is not working correctly, or am I missing something.

lspci shows the correct device

```
$ lspci | grep Broad
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller (rev 01)
```

I up the wlan0 with the following command

```
$ ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Could you tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Does wlan0 have a local IP?

Comment: maybe problem with wifi (see [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/253632/6228))

Comment: @xaccrocheur No, it doesn't.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. It was an internal card and the system detected it. The drivers were loaded, but it found no wireless networks.

It was an antenna issue. I connected the antenna leads and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible drivers for your device, the native brcmsmac and bcmwl-kernel-source, also known as the STA driver. STA creates a wireless interface eth1 and not wlan0. Is the result the same if you try:

```
sudo iwlist eth1 scan
```

Moreover, depending on your Ubuntu version one or the other driver works better.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching your wifi on using the manual button you have on your keyboard, or a manual switch.

This solved my wifi issue.

If it doesn't show the wifi driver or issues with the driver, then you can install the drivers first and disable secure boot.