# On 13.10, wifi gets detected but unable to connect

Tags: wireless, 13.10, network-manager, bluetooth, ralink

I am running Ubuntu 13.10, my system detects WiFi but I'm unable to connect.

I am getting this error message:

```
r[736]: (wlan0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> disconnected 
r[736]: (wlan0): supplicant interface state: disconnected -> scanning 4.472788] ieee80211 phy0: 
rt2x00queue_write_tx_frame: Error - Arrived at non-free entry in the non-full queue 0 4.472788] 
Please file bug report to http://rt2x00.serialmonkey.com
```

How can I fix this ?

With the below reply by Pushpreet, Wifi is working, but still bluetooth never works, any suggestions?

Comment: I am not sure how to fix this some say to update to kernel 3.12?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a lot of assumptions here, because you haven't really given a lot of information, I think that your WiFi card is Ralink RT3290.

I had the same problem and fought hard to fix this.

There are numerous fixes, I tried them, and none worked, finally found one which was the easiest and worked flawlessly, and yes, that involves upgrading your kernel.

Here, this will help:

https://askubuntu.com/a/377973/216304

Comment: Thank You Pushpreet, I will try it and let you know the results. And yes it is Ralink RT3290, bluetooth also never works..hopefully upgrading the kernel fixes it.

Comment: IT worked,thanks, can you help me with Bluetooth too? It never works. My laptop is a HP 2229TU, wireless card by Ralink RT3290,

Comment: Sachinanto, I am glad the fix worked for you, I a sorry I haven't yet tried to fix my bluetooth, I never use it on a laptop, wait till April, I think 14.04 would fix it.

Comment: Hopefully :) I was on it even today.. And do you have any idea if ubuntu actually slows down wifi, sound like a myth...but mine is slow..may be my router is the culprit...