# Wireless card not working (Atheros 9287)

Tags: wireless, drivers, 13.10

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 some days ago in my Desktop, which has installed a TP-LINK WN881ND. The problem is that Ubuntu don't find any networks to connect, even though there's, at least, 5 networks in my region - the other OS (Windows 8) detects the board.

Is there any solution for this? I've been searching for a solution for weeks and no one seems to solve the problem.

Note: My network access is purely based on wireless, so I can't access the internet on Ubuntu, just on the Windows.

Info:
Model: TL-WN881ND
Chipset: ATHEROS 9287

Edit
Thanks to Julian, now I can see some of the connections. However, the one that I use in home doesn't showed up.

Answer (score 1):

Did it work in 13.04? I had a similar problem with 13.10 (worked fine in 13.04), but with a different wireless card (Ralink RT3290). The solution was to upgrade the Linux kernel to 3.12 from 3.11. The instructions given in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/377973/139634) work fine. I also didn't have an Ethernet to get the .deb files. I used another machine and transfer them with a USB. Worth a try?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it fixed some part of the problem; now I can see some of the connections. Unfortunately, my house's one hasn't appeared, although it has almost 70% of signal quality in the Windows.

Comment: What happens if you try connect to a hidden wireless network and put in the SSID and password (even though it is not hidden). This worked in Windows ages ago with my netbook and a weird missing wifi connection.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It still doesn't work..