# how to install Ralink 3290 wireless adaptor in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, kernel, ralink

I'm using Ralink rt3290 wireless card in my ubuntu 12.04 lts running kernel version `3.5.0-23-generic`

I used the steps showed in the question [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working)

It installed successfully but later on I got error

`kernel panic not syncing fatal exception in interrupt`

I found out that this is due to the wireless adaptor I installed I switched back to ethernet card and I didn't got that error again. Now my question is how can I make my wireless card work in Ubuntu 12.04. Will I have to update my kernel and how can I do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution to my problem for all those who are facing the same problem here are the steps I followed:

You need to connect ethernet interface of the system to the internet to install the necessary packages. I believe you have a working internet connection then follow these steps:

1. Install additional driver's in Ubuntu.

   While installing Ubuntu 12.04 I had to check the mark which shows to install additional third party softwares and drivers during installation:

Check the box which says Install third party softwares.

[image]

2.After installation has finished you will be presented with default kernel of Ubuntu 12.04.

In my case it was `3.5`

So, now install the kernel version `3.6.11` get its packages from the link below:

[Kernel PPA](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/)

Download the kernel files from above link then install the files using the command:

```
dpkg -i file-name
```

then

```
update-grub
```

and

```
reboot
```

Your system will reboot now if everything done right you will no be running kernel version `3.6.11` you can check it by the command `uname -a`

3.After successfull installation of linux kernel `3.6.11` when you will check in the networks it will show an error stating `Firmware missing`

so now we will copy the firmware of ralink rt3290 to the directory `/lib/firmware`

Get the ralink rt3290 firmware using the command:

```
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/dwmw2/linux-firmware.git
```

then copy the firmware

```
cp linux-firmware/rt3290.bin /lib/firmware
```

then

`reboot`

After the reboot has finished your wifi should be working now and without any kernel panic errors. This solution worked for me in `Ubuntu 12.04` hope it helps others as well.