# Help with the RT3290 Wireless adapter

Tags: wireless, drivers, xubuntu, ralink

I know there is a lot of questions about RT3290 wireless adapter, but I read many many of them and noone helped me with my problem. 
So, I have the HP Pavilion dm1 laptop and I installed Xubuntu 13.10 on it. During the instalation it poped up that I'm able to connect to the internet via network adapter. I did it obviously, but it worked for like 5 seconds, then it said that network connection is down and I couldn't connect to my router, even if i could actually see network connections avaible. Then (when installation ended) I rebooted my computer. My network was avaible! I could connect and browse the internet smoothly. Next day I turned on my laptop and I saw my wireless connection is no longer avaible, so I plugged laptop to the internet via Ethernet cable and started to explore internet searching solution for my problem. I did this:

[How do I get a Ralink RT3290 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working)

And I was able to connect BUT my kernel started to panic every time I started Mozilla or any program that is connecting to the internet. Every tip i searched was almost the same as the link above. I tried to do this many ways. I even Reinstalled Xubuntu to do everything with clear system but the same thing happened. THEN I installed Linux Mint to check whether it is a major or just Xubuntu problem. Linux Mint responded even worse, because I wasn't even able to use terminal (I clearly messed something up).

I would really, really appreciate every help, because I do want to solve this problem and finally be able to use Xubuntu/Ubuntu. I'm waiting for advice from anyone patiently. If anyone wants some details, just tell me which ones.

Comment: This post surely works. My wifi signal strength has improved but the stability is not there. Wifi disconnects every now and then, does not stay more than 10 minutes

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the file.

   https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7kbO9nS2qKEMmQ5elZXVUhDRjA/edit?pli=1
2. Copy the folder named "rt3290sta-2.6.0.0" to `/usr/src/`.

   i. Check the folder name again! The name should be `rt3290sta-2.6.0.0`.

   ii. You cannot copy files to `/usr/src/`? Open the terminal and run:

   ```
    gksudo nautilus
   ```

   Then a GUI window will open. Browse to Computer -> usr -> src, and paste the folder.
3. In the terminal run:

   ```
   sudo dkms install -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 –force
   ```