# Ralink RT3290 wifi drops every 5 minutes

Tags: wireless, ralink

I have HP Pavilion G6-2201ax laptop. After a year or so I could install a good driver for my wireless device. [Help with the RT3290 Wireless adapter](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402393/help-with-the-rt3290-wireless-adapter). Now connection is good and strong. But new problem is that wifi drops every 5 minutes. I have to reconnect it everytime. Please help. I have disabled 802.11n also tried wicd network manager. Nothing helps.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using ubuntu wifi manager. Try to remove your network from manager and configure it in /etc/network/interfaces, you will find instructions here:https://wiki.debian.org/WiFi/HowToUse if the problem resolves itself then it's managers fault.

Comment: I do not know how to configure network in /etc/network/interfaces

Comment: read the link I sent you

Answer (score 2):

Write this:
**sudo iwconfig**

Now, find your adapter name-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1PZsf.png

**sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off**

Replace 'wlan0' with yours.

Comment: How does it answer the question and what can you find out from iwconfig? Maybe dmesg or /var/log/kern.log would tell more?

Comment: If it works when plugged in (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1597874) but not when on battery the power saving feature may be causing disconnects.

Comment: It disconnects both during battery and when connected to power

Comment: Tried everything given here. Nothing works. Instead of wlan0, it shows ra0

Comment: Now I have good wifi signal and good speed but unstable wifi. Disconnects every now and then. Does not stay more than 10 minutes.