# Trying to install a wireless driver rt3290 receiving two make errors

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers

I have a new computer, I decided to go for Ubuntu instead of other operating systems. However, I cannot seem to get my wireless to work. My wireless seems to be picking up other networks (not my own). I've tried a bunch of fixes, I have landed on [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working) I don't even know if I need to use this fix, but I have been trying everything. The problem with this fix is when I follow the steps and type `make` I get a make error 1 & 2. I don't know if the driver is already installed on my machine, since I can pick up other wifi signals, although they are all password blocked so I can't check if I can connect to them. This is driving me absolutely nuts. Although I guess this is teaching me how to use Ubuntu the hard way. If you need specific info to help me let me know and I will provide it.

Comment: First things first. Connect to your router by ethernet cable and make sure that the WiFi is ON. Then make sure that your SSID is being broadcast and set the appropriate passwords for a secure connection (WPA/WPA2). Now disconnect cable and try connecting by wireless.

Comment: I have other computers the wireless itself is working fine.

Comment: Type `modprobe -l rt3290` in terminal. If you get no output then the module is missing. Also it would be nice if you could capture the output from make and include it in your question.

Comment: modprobe did not work. So I tried it without -l and this is what came up. jody@Megatron:~$ modprobe -l rt3290
modprobe: invalid option -- 'l'
jody@Megatron:~$ modprobe rt3290
FATAL: Module rt3290 not found.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [This](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=571188) post on configuring wpa_supplicant.

Comment: jody@Megatron:~$ sudo lspci | grep -i network
[sudo] password for jody: 
03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe