# Wifi internet help needed

Tags: wireless, madwifi

I am new to Ubuntu. For a few minutes after turning on my laptop the internet will work, and then it will disconnect. It normally stays connected for 5-15 minutes, then it will disconnect and I won't be able to connect unless I restart the laptop.
Someone please help !!!! Thank you.

I tried following the instructions in the answer to this question: [How do I get a Ralink RT3290 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working) by Luis Alvarado, but it didn't work.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Complex [1022:1410]
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Richland [Radeon HD 8550G] [1002:990d]
00:01.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Trinity HDMI Audio Controller [1002:9902]
00:04.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Root Port [1022:1414]
00:10.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller [1022:7814] (rev 09)
00:10.1 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB XHCI Controller [1022:7814] (rev 09)
00:11.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] [1022:7804]
00:12.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller [1022:7807] (rev 11)
00:12.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller [1022:7808] (rev 11)
00:13.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB OHCI Controller [1022:7807] (rev 11)
00:13.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH USB EHCI Controller [1022:7808] (rev 11)
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller [1022:780b] (rev 16)
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH Azalia Controller [1022:780d] (rev 01)
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge [1022:780e] (rev 11)
00:14.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH PCI Bridge [1022:780f] (rev 40)
00:15.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 0) [1022:43a0]
00:15.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 1) [1022:43a1]
00:15.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Hudson PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3) [1022:43a3]
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 0 [1022:1400]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 1 [1022:1401]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 2 [1022:1402]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 3 [1022:1403]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 4 [1022:1404]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h (Models 10h-1fh) Processor Function 5 [1022:1405]
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
04:00.1 Bluetooth [0d11]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth [1814:3298]
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5229] (rev 01)
```

Comment: If your device is built in to the laptop, it is most likely a PCI device and can be identified from a terminal command: `lspci -nn`. You can list only devices of the class 'wireless networking' with: `lspci -nn | grep 0280`. Running these commands will help to provide information about the model of wireless adapter in your laptop.

Comment: @karel It wouldn't let me add it as a comment, so I edited my original post.

Comment: @karel 04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]

Comment: The answers to this question: [How do I get a Ralink RT3290 wireless card working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working) might help, especially the first answer by Luis Alvarado.

Comment: @karel Thank you for taking the time to answer my question.

Comment: @karel Its not working. I'm trying my best but to no avail.

Comment: @Luis Alvarado I need help

Comment: Which Ubuntu version are you using? lsb_release -a. If it is 12.04, which kernel: uname -r Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 3.11.0-12-generic. Thank you for coming btw

Comment: I still need lsb_release -d Thanks.

Comment: @chili555 Ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the most productive thing you might try is to compile the backported driver from kernel version 3.13. Please get a temporary wired ethernet, USB modem, tethered or any reliable internet connection. Open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential
```

Download this file to your desktop: http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v3.13.2/backports-3.13.2-1.tar.xz  Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now back to the terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/backports-3.13.2-1
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

The process takes some time; please be patient. After it completes, you may get a warning about signing which you may safely ignore. Reboot and let us have your report.

I understand you may have tried several techniques. Do you have a parameter file? We ought to see what is in it and decide if we still need it:

```
cat /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf
```

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7191759/ This was the output

Comment: Please proceed. I compiled the package on my 13.10 system earlier and there should be no problems. Go!

Comment: Type "Y", right ?

Comment: Yessir! Every chance you get.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7191834/

Comment: Are you sure you are connected to the internet reliably?

Comment: It's connect for like 5 minutes after I turn on the laptop then it disconnects and stays disconnected until I restart it. The shorter answer is no

Comment: You will have much better luck if you walk the computer over to the router and hook up an ethernet cable.

Comment: I plugged my laptop directly to it and I still no internet access. The Ethernet cord is in the Ethernet port and I still can't browse the web.

Comment: And I'm getting the same error.

Comment: Does Network Manager recognize the ethernet and report you are connected?

Comment: I just got it connected, but do you think I should just go back to windows? I had Ubuntu three days and its been nothing but trouble.

Comment: It is entirely up to you. I'd try the remaining steps first, if it were me. Once you get wireless sorted, it is pretty smooth.

Comment: Now it's telling me to insert disc. Did you go through all this too ?

Comment: Now im replying to on the Ubuntu laptop, but I cant run any off the commands.

Comment: Please find Software Sources and de-select the CD as a source, agree to reload the package index and try again.