# WiFi disconnect frequently on Ubuntu 14.04 (Ralink RT3290)

Tags: wireless, drivers, ralink

I have a problem with my WiFi Ralink RT3290. I followed all the instructions according to "[Ralink rt3290 wifi driver is not working in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455030/ralink-rt3290-wifi-driver-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04)".

Now that my WiFi works, but every hour it happens that data is flowing, although Ubuntu indicates that the WiFi is connected. It is always necessary to disconnect and connect to WiFi or network, and then it works again.

How can I get this fixed?

Comment: Do you mean that the data stops flowing every hour?

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: I am also at same spot with a HP pavilion g4. I checked and rfkill didn't do it. But this disconnection is going on and on. I hope someone got answer for it.

Comment: [Bug #1049466 - 
Need support of Ralink RT3290 wifi support](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1049466)

Comment: I have the same problem with my laptop too.. :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wifi internet help needed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441788/wifi-internet-help-needed)