# Internet drops download for a few seconds every 30 or so seconds

Tags: networking, ethernet, realtek

This problem occurs whenever I stream data, for example every 30 seconds in a skype call I wont be able to hear the other party for about 5 seconds but they can hear me. Playing an online game I run into the same problem where I disconnect for 5 seconds. I use a Ethernet and didn't have any problems with windows 8.

I find it very likely that you might need other information from me so I will stand by.

Edit: I'm using Ubuntu 16.04

Edit: My result from running `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`

```
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0c)
DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:2af3]
Kernel driver in use: r8168
Kernel modules: r8168
```

04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]

Comment: Is "Ethernet" a cable connection?

Comment: @Pilot6 yes it is

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` terminal command. And what is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: What is the Ubuntu version?

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm using 16.04

Comment: Which kernel? `uname -a`?

Comment: Linux jan-700-230qe 4.8.0-53-generic #56~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Tue May 16 01:18:56 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wifi internet help needed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441788/wifi-internet-help-needed)

Answer (score 1):

Install a vendor driver for this chipset by running

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/r/r8168/r8168-dkms_8.042.00-2_all.deb
sudo apt install dkms
sudo dpkg -i r8168-dkms_8.042.00-2_all.deb
```

Comment: If you get errors on the 4.8 kernel, tell me.

Comment: Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.8.0-53-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/r8168/8.041.00/build/make.log for more information.

Comment: I tested it too. The package in repo is for kernel 4.4. I updated the answer.

Comment: I ran these lines, installed the package, and restarted my machine but am still having the same issue.

Comment: Hm, it is mysterious. What does `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` show now? Please add it to the question.

Comment: After I run dpkg one of the things it tells me is `Secure Boot not enabled on this system.` do I need do enable secure boot?

Comment: You need to disable it.

Comment: alright I edited in the new return for `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3`

Comment: The driver installed OK. So the issue is somewhere else.