# Wireless disconnects after downloading certain amount bytes

Tags: 16.04, wireless

I have a brand new system running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Windows 10. My system is up to date. I've tried several things found here, but none of them worked for me.

Basically, my wireless <del>connection dropped</del> disconnects after I downloaded around 400 MB. After that, somehow it went through that limit, but now I won't be able to download more than 1.2 GB. I have power management powered off for my wireless card, but that doesn't help.

I tried with Windows 10 and did not have any issues.

Last thing, trying `sudo service network-manager restart` or disconnecting won't get my connection back. Only by restarting I would get my connection back.

This is what I got from this post: [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

[My wireless info](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Kkyhdqn55j/)

EDIT: (6/24/18)

I forgot to mention the following:

- I guess I probably used the wrong word. I wanted to say it disconnected instead of dropped. It's not that it will download at a slower speed, but rather won't download at all.

- I just suffer this weird bug with this computer (using Linux). I had a laptop and I didn't experience this disconnections at all with it (it was also dual boot between Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10).

- I have a Smart TV, a smart phone and a tablet PC and never suffered any disconnections, though I don't think I have met the 1.2 GB with any of those.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

[image: Screenshot 3]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wifi internet help needed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/441788/wifi-internet-help-needed)

Answer (score 0):

Your paste shows this:

```
Cell 01 - Address: <MAC 'ATT4mHb53Z' [AC1]>
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=70/70  Signal level=-40 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"ATT4mHb53Z"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                              24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
```

And this:

```
Channel occupancy:

      8   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
      2   APs on   Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.427 GHz (Channel 4)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.432 GHz (Channel 5)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
      1   APs on   Frequency:2.442 GHz (Channel 7)
      5   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
```

Did you select channel 1 intentionally, not realizing that it is the most congested channel in your area? Or, more likely, is your router set to auto-select the channel. This interesting post shows why auto-select is a very bad idea: https://superuser.com/questions/1311149/why-do-wifi-routers-do-such-a-bad-job-of-channel-selection

Please set your router to a fixed channel, ideally channel 6, and tell us if the connectivity is improved.

**EDIT**: Check all of the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Any improvement?

**EDIT 2**: Please try a driver parameter. From the terminal:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rt2800pci nohwcrypt=Y"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf
exit
```

Reboot. Any improvement?

**EDIT 3**: In you log, we see dozens of entries:

```
rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 2 failed to flush
```

Here is a post that describes your issue exactly; the wireless disconnects and nothing short of a reboot helps: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=237028 Notice that the log messages are the same and there is no real solution. There is a suggestion that it is a hardware issue.

Here is another, with the same log messages; definitely a hardware issue: https://forum.lede-project.org/t/solved-wireless-interruption-on-zyxel-p2812hnu-f1/11088/9

Here is another with no solution: [Ubuntu 16.04 Weak WiFi Signal after dual boot Ralink Rt3290](https://askubuntu.com/questions/950115/ubuntu-16-04-weak-wifi-signal-after-dual-boot-ralink-rt3290)

I suggest that you make sure that the card is seating correctly in its PCI slot. If you still have trouble, I suggest that you consider replacing the card. If you do so, be certain to blacklist the driver rt2800pci for the internal device.

Comment: Thank chili555. I have just noticed I was reading a post where you were trying to help a guy thad had a similar king of issue (his connection dropped after 1 minute). 

Anyway, I tried moving from automatic channel to #6, and that didn't help. I realized after downloading 400 MB my computer disconnected, and I couldn't even access my router. When you disconnect to try to reconnect, I will stay trying with no success. 

Having read some other posts, do you think I should try rt3562sta driver and blacklisting rt2800pci?

Comment: I just wanted to add one more thing, because you probably won't read the title again. I just wanted to clarify that my speed doesn't actually drop, but that I experience disconnection. <br> Sorry about that.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few minutes. I will add some additional suggestions.

Comment: All the settings you mentioned are set as default in my router. I should also mention 5 GHz radio is enabled, and I don't know if that would affect and if I should turn it off. This is also the output on **REG GET** `sudo iw reg get
[sudo] password for zo1984: 
country US: DFS-FCC
 (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
 (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (N/A)
 (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
 (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 23), (0 ms), DFS
 (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 30), (N/A)
 (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 40), (N/A)` @chili555

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand. Are you saying that, for instance, auto WPA or WPA2 is set as default and that you are unable or unwilling to switch to a more suitable fixed WPA2?

Comment: I added a couple of screenshots. I was trying to explain that those settings you recommended were already set like that, no need to change anything except for **/etc/default/crda**. I also forgot to say that I still experience certain limit of bytes and connection will die.

Comment: @Fabby Sorry, I didn't understand your comment. ;)

Comment: @Fabby and I are working on another issue and he used this post to reach me. You may safely ignore his comments.

Comment: Your 5 GHz is still on auto channel select, although I doubt that your device does 5 GHz. Check: `sudo iwlist freq`

Comment: `lo        no frequency information.

wlp5s0    11 channels in total; available frequencies :
          Channel 01 : 2.412 GHz
          Channel 02 : 2.417 GHz
          Channel 03 : 2.422 GHz
          Channel 04 : 2.427 GHz
          Channel 05 : 2.432 GHz
          Channel 06 : 2.437 GHz
          Channel 07 : 2.442 GHz
          Channel 08 : 2.447 GHz
          Channel 09 : 2.452 GHz
          Channel 10 : 2.457 GHz
          Channel 11 : 2.462 GHz
          Current Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)

enp3s0    no frequency information.`

Comment: Just as an experiment, disable the 5 GHz segment in the router, reboot it and tell us if the disconnects are solved. We can revert in a few moments after the test. I wonder if the router is trying to move to a 5GHz channel but can't detect that the Ubuntu wireless device can't go there.

Comment: Nope. Once it reaches around 1GB, my connection is still gone, even after I disabled 5GHz radio. I was wondering, is there any place where I can find some sort of logs about what is happening to my connection?

Comment: Please check: `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e wlp -e rt2` As the result will probably be lengthy, use http://paste.ubuntu.com and give us the link. You might also try a driver parameter; see my edit #2 in a few minutes.

Comment: This is what I got from syslog: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/mzbMQVGsmJ/. Around 5:05 (my current time) I got disconnected, but nothing was logged regarding any issue. This is also after I tried driver parameter, as you suggested.

Comment: Please see my edit above in a few moments.

Comment: I will try reseating the card. I have read the posts you linked for me and I couldn't  find any useful information. It's totally weird, I don't have any issues with my other linux system (different wireless card) or using this same computer with Windows 10. It's a shame, since I don't want to switch to Windows other than for playing games, and at the same time I wouldn't like to buy an ethernet cable since I prefer wireless. Anyway, I let you know if I have any news. Thanks for all your help. :)

Comment: Hi again chili555. I tried reseating the card, but no progress. I tried moving closer to my router and that didn't help either. I also tried detaching one antenna at a time (my card has 2), but it still gets disconnected. If you have any other suggestion I will try it. Otherwise I guess I will buy an ethernet cable.

Comment: I have no other suggestions. I would consider buying a different PCI wireless card or a USB wireless.

Answer (score 0):

### From your network info below:

Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3062 Wireless 802.11n 2T/2R [1814:3062]
    Subsystem: Ralink corp. RT3062 Wireless 802.11n 2T/2R [1814:3062]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci

It shows that your wireless interface is RT3062, but it didn't show in your "lsmod list", it seems that this module isn't installed in your computer, so you have to install firmware 'rt3062' first. Hope it helps.