# Ralink rt3290 wifi driver is not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless

I recently upgraded from ubuntu 13.10 to ubuntu 14.04. Wifi (with ralink rt3290 card) was not working in ubuntu 13.10, but after the following the guide here, [How do I get a Ralink RT3290 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working), it worked fine. But in ubuntu 14.04, no matter how much I try it does not work. Can anyone please figure out what the problem is and how to solve it.

Answer (score 20):

Download the file from [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7kbO9nS2qKEMmQ5elZXVUhDRjA) and follow the following steps:

1. Extract the `rt3290sta-2.6.0.0` directory into `/usr/src`.
2. Run `sudo dkms install -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 --force`.
3. Reboot.

And you should be good :)

[Source](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1049466)

Comment: `dkms` wasn't installed on this system by default (originally a trusty beta install)...

Comment: Cool!
Please mark the thread resolved!

Comment: It's a shame that OP didn't mark this as solved, rahul.  Your answer was spot on!  Thanks for posting it.

Comment: Sir, thank you for posting this answer. I can confirm it works on Ubuntu 14.04, HP Probook 4540s after following this guide. Real shame the author didn't mark the thread as solved.

Comment: I'm having this problem with Bluetooth. WiFi works fine. Any suggestions for that? (HP Pavilion 15-n240tx)

Comment: No go for me.. I'm using Ubuntu 14.10, with kernel 3.16.0-24-generic  The GCC compiler spits out lots of warning errors.    Errors relating to int / long unsigned int / Wpointer to int cast / ulong to unsigned int ... I'm under the strong impression that HP purchased the cheapest WIFI modules around, the supporting company (Ralink) went out of business and HP refuses to support.  Had I known this laptop couldn't be converted to Linux I would have bought elsewhere...  Anybody good on C/C++  (and understand the driver system?)

Comment: to remove these drivers sudo dkms remove rt3290sta/2.6.0.0 --all