# Ubuntu 14.04 rt3290 driver is not working, soft blocked

Tags: wireless, 14.04, bug-reporting, ralink

In Ubuntu 14.04, WiFi driver is not working.

I completed this suggest [Ralink rt3290 wifi driver is not working in Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455030/ralink-rt3290-wifi-driver-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04) but nothing better.

I just did following this 
[How do I get a Ralink RT3290 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working)
but there is error at step 6 when I typed "make".

This is more information:

```
$ rfkill list

0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN

Soft blocked: yes 
Hard blocked: no
```

and

```
nuttapon@Clarent:~$ lshw
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
clarent                   
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 0
          size: 3796MiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700HQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 1
          bus info: cpu@0
          size: 800MHz
          capacity: 800MHz
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cpufreq
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 06
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 06
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:42 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:f6000000-f70fffff ioport:c0000000(size=301989888)
           *-display
                description: 3D controller
                product: GK107M [GeForce GT 745M]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
                resources: irq:50 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:46 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:47 memory:f7a14000-f7a17fff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:43 memory:f7a00000-f7a0ffff
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:45 memory:f7a1e000-f7a1e00f
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:f7a1c000-f7a1c3ff
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:48 memory:f7a10000-f7a13fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: d4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:af200000-af3fffff ioport:af400000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: d4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:18 memory:f7900000-f79fffff
           *-network DISABLED
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
                vendor: Ralink corp.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: ra0
                version: 00
                serial: 1c:3e:84:c1:09:d7
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA
                resources: irq:18 memory:f7910000-f791ffff
           *-generic UNCLAIMED
                description: Bluetooth
                product: RT3290 Bluetooth
                vendor: Ralink corp.
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:f7900000-f790ffff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: d4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:19 ioport:d000(size=4096) memory:f7800000-f78fffff
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet
                vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 10
                serial: 74:d0:2b:c4:54:14
                size: 100Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=alx duplex=full ip=192.168.1.39 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
                resources: irq:49 memory:f7800000-f783ffff ioport:d000(size=128)
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:23 memory:f7a1b000-f7a1b3ff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: HM86 Express LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:44 ioport:f0b0(size=8) ioport:f0a0(size=4) ioport:f090(size=8) ioport:f080(size=4) ioport:f060(size=32) memory:f7a1a000-f7a1a7ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: latency=0
             resources: memory:f7a19000-f7a190ff ioport:f040(size=32)
     *-scsi
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: DVD-RAM UJ8C2 S
             vendor: MATSHITA
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: 1.00
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=open
```

and

```
nuttapon@Clarent:~$ sudo lspci -v
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11ed
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>

00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=01, subordinate=01, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000e000-0000efff
    Memory behind bridge: f6000000-f70fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000c0000000-00000000d1ffffff
    Capabilities: [88] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11ed
    Capabilities: [80] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [a0] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [140] Root Complex Link
    Capabilities: [d94] #19
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11ed
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 46
    Memory at f7400000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4M]
    Memory at b0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: [90] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [a4] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: i915

00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11ed
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at f7a14000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 04) (prog-if 30 [XHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 201f
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 43
    Memory at f7a00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11ed
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 45
    Memory at f7a1e000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [8c] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me

00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11ed
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
    Memory at f7a1c000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11ed
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 48
    Memory at f7a10000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [60] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel

00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=02, subordinate=02, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 00002000-00002fff
    Memory behind bridge: af200000-af3fffff
    Prefetchable memory behind bridge: 00000000af400000-00000000af5fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot-), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11ed
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=03, subordinate=03, sec-latency=0
    Memory behind bridge: f7900000-f79fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11ed
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d4) (prog-if 00 [Normal decode])
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Bus: primary=00, secondary=04, subordinate=04, sec-latency=0
    I/O behind bridge: 0000d000-0000dfff
    Memory behind bridge: f7800000-f78fffff
    Capabilities: [40] Express Root Port (Slot+), MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [90] Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11ed
    Capabilities: [a0] Power Management version 3
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport

00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 04) (prog-if 20 [EHCI])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11ed
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 23
    Memory at f7a1b000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=1K]
    Capabilities: [50] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [58] Debug port: BAR=1 offset=00a0
    Capabilities: [98] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci

00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11ed
    Flags: bus master, medium devsel, latency 0
    Capabilities: [e0] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich

00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04) (prog-if 01 [AHCI 1.0])
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11ed
    Flags: bus master, 66MHz, medium devsel, latency 0, IRQ 44
    I/O ports at f0b0 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f0a0 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f090 [size=8]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=4]
    I/O ports at f060 [size=32]
    Memory at f7a1a000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2K]
    Capabilities: [80] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [a8] SATA HBA v1.0
    Kernel driver in use: ahci

00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11ed
    Flags: medium devsel, IRQ 3
    Memory at f7a19000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256]
    I/O ports at f040 [size=32]

01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 745M] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 11ed
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 50
    Memory at f6000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at c0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    Memory at d0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=32M]
    I/O ports at e000 [size=128]
    Expansion ROM at f7000000 [disabled] [size=512K]
    Capabilities: [60] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [68] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [78] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [b4] Vendor Specific Information: Len=14 <?>
    Capabilities: [100] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [128] Power Budgeting <?>
    Capabilities: [600] Vendor Specific Information: ID=0001 Rev=1 Len=024 <?>
    Capabilities: [900] #19
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau

03:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device e055
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 18
    Memory at f7910000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-00-d7-09-c1-84-3e-1c
    Kernel driver in use: rt2860

03:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device e056
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 3
    Memory at f7900000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-00-d8-09-c1-84-3e-1c

04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8171 Gigabit Ethernet (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Qualcomm Atheros Device 1091
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 49
    Memory at f7800000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
    I/O ports at d000 [size=128]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [58] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [c0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/16 Maskable+ 64bit+
    Capabilities: [d8] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [180] Device Serial Number ff-c4-54-14-74-d0-2b-ff
    Kernel driver in use: alx
```

What should I do?
Thank you in advance.

when I type `sudo make` or `make`, I got this error

```
make[2]: *** [/home/nuttapon/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../os/linux/rt_linux.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/nuttapon/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-24-generic'
make: *** [LINUX] Error 2
```

Comment: Please use back ticks (``) to bracket your code output.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the command in step 6 of [How do I get a Ralink RT3290 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working)

to

```
sudo make

sudo make install
```

let us know if the error message persists and exactly what the error is.

Thank you for providing the error message. It appears as if you may not be running the commands in the directory where the source code resides. Try changing to the directory where you extracted the source code and proviide us a list of the contents `ls`

Comment: I changed the code already. Even I change the code there are still same errors and I added the error message. Thanks for your help.