# Ralink RT3290 wifi driver is not working in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, wireless, ralink

I tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455030/ralink-rt3290-wifi-driver-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04/455512#455512?newreg=7ddbefb92fc948e2a0c249004bbb467b) but I got this error:

```
sudo dkms install -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 --force
Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/rt3290sta-2.6.0.0 does not exist.
```

Answer (score 0):

I followed these [instructions](http://www.dailylinuxnews.com/blog/2014/09/install-ralink-rt3290-wifi-driver-in-ubuntu-linuxmint-elementaryos/) and they fixed my issue with the WiFi card on my HP 650.

The WiFi card is now working again, as it was on 12.04, but the Bluetooth don't.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

This is independent from your Ubuntu version but depends on the kernel version, I've managed to install it on Ubuntu 15.04 (and also works in Ubuntu 14.10).

- Downgrade kernel version to linux-image-3.16.0-34
- Download [rt3920 drivers for this kernel](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9PSRQzQuCHWN2FfaDFGYm44cUE/view?usp=sharing)
- Install **dkms**: `sudo apt-get install dkms`
- Extract file to /usr/src: `sudo tar -xvf rt3290sta-2.6.0.0.dkms.tar -C /usr/src`
- `cd /usr/src`
- `sudo dkms install -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 --force`
- Restart the computer and wifi should work.
- Verify your module is working checking the output of: `lspci -v`

  Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe

  ```
  **Kernel driver in use: rt2860** *(2860 works also for 3290)*
  ```
- Note: If something goes wrong uninstall the patch: `sudo dkms remove rt3290sta/2.6.0.0 --all`

**Please, if you test the method in newer kernel versions, consider posting it in the comments so we can safely upgrade it**