# Wifi speed is significently low compare to windows os in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (RT3290 wifi wireless router)

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, wireless, drivers

I got a new wireless router TP-LINK today. **The router was working well with windows os in my laptop. But when I switched back to ubuntu 14.04 (dual boot with windows os) The speed was significantly lower.** I am using `Ralink rt3290 wifi router`. Please help me with the problem, it's really annoying.

Comment: Please run the commands with `LANG=C` prefix. It  will give output in English.

Comment: How are you measuring "slower"?

Comment: I am using http://www.speedtest.net/ website to measure Internet speed

Comment: @Pilot6 I have change the output in english.

Comment: What numbers do you get exactly?

Comment: @ssta for ubuntu download speed 7.79 Mbps and upload speed is 2.45 Mbps
for windows download speed 34.07 Mbps and upload speed is 2.15 Mbps

Comment: i had the same issue, tried solution from here http://www.hitxp.com/articles/software/ubuntu-fix-slow-wireless-internet-connection-speed-upgrading-11-04-natty-narwhal/

now it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by installing driver for Ralink rt3290. I followed this procedure.

1. Download driver from [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B7kbO9nS2qKEMmQ5elZXVUhDRjA/edit).
2. Install dkms by `sudo apt-get install dkms`
3. Extract the rt3290sta-2.6.0.0 directory into /usr/src.
4. Run sudo dkms install -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 --force.
5. Reboot.

I follow this [SOURCE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455030/ralink-rt3290-wifi-driver-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04/455512#455512?newreg=7ddbefb92fc948e2a0c249004bbb467b).

Answer (score 1):

This is well known [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1449090) with kernel drivers for this adapter.

You can vote there that the bug affects you too.

Or report another bug, since that one is marked as invalid.

Comment: So what can I do now. Should I Upgrade from ubuntu 14.04 to ubuntu 15.04. will it help?

Comment: It will not help, since there is the same driver. You can report a bug by running `ubuntu-bug linux`.