# Ralink rt3290 wifi driver is not working properly in Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 15.04, ralink

I am new to Ubuntu. I have also looked into other threads but not able to find proper solution. After few minutes of logging in network goes off even though network manager shows signal (or when wifi signal drops just a little bit). [Using this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/455030/ralink-rt3290-wifi-driver-is-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04) ,got the below error.

ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for rt3290sta: 2.6.0.0 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 3.19.0-33-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/rt3290sta/2.6.0.0/build/make.log for more information.

[This is result of network script](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13455086/)
Please help me on this.