# sub par wifi with 12.04 kernel 3.2.0-29 an proprietary RT3290

Tags: 12.04, wireless, kernel

I have a HP Pavillion 500-203A with RT3290 chipset and simply inserted by own Ubuntu 12.04 disk. I successfully compiled the proprietary drivers according to this guide: https://askubuntu.com/a/253660/22921 (one of its alternative versions somewhere), but only with Kernel 3.2.0-29

The connection is stable, no 3290 related messages appear in dmesg, but the connection is somewhat slower than on cable:

Cable connection is http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/3624414085

Wifi connection is http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/3624419046

I find it strange that download speed is slower than upload?

Any ideas on how to improve on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by chance looking into by computer case again. It seems by accident I removed one of the 2 wireless antenna cables from the motherboard. The wifi speed is now comparable to cable connection