# Wlan disconnects often

Tags: wireless, 14.04, drivers, gnome

I am using a lenovo T440 with Ubuntu 14.04, Gnome 3.10.4 and Kernel 3.13.0-32-generic. My WLAN disconnects often. So I researched a bit about the problem and found out that maybe the module isn't fitting.

So, in my Notebook is a Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. **RTL8192EE** PCIe Wireless Network Adapter which needs (maybe) the module RTL8192E. I am not 100% sure. Right now it loads the module Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 which I found out through

```
lspci -nnk
```

Edit from Comments:

```
 lspci -nn | grep 0280
```

Result: Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 6b)

Anyway I found the module for my wlan adapter in

```
/lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192e/rtl8192e/r8192e_pci.ko
```

and I had the idea to load this module and let replace the old module. But if I want to load it with

```
insmod /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/staging/rtl8192e/rtl8192e/r8192e_pci.ko
```

it is refused by

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module rtl8192e/r8192e_pci.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

I can't see the solution. Am I taking the right path? Is the module replacement the right choice? Does anyone see the solution?

Comment: There are problems with wifi since long time ago. You can try this : http://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working

Comment: What does this tell us about the device? lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b2] (rev 6b)
is the response