# How to install wifi driver Ralink RT3290

Tags: wireless, drivers, ralink

I'm new to Ubuntu. How can i install wifi driver Ralink RT3290 802.11bgn? And please if you can help me step by step :D Thank you very much!

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you running? What version of the kernel? What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have ubuntu 14.10 and kernel should be latest version, i updateted it. I'm not very good at this. I tried instaling with tutorilas on the internet, but allways something miss. When i try commands make install, it says there are errors

Comment: Aren't the drivers included with Ubuntu? I have a Belkin F7D1101 v2 that uses the same chipset and it has worked fine in Ubuntu 13.10, 14.04. and 14.10.

Comment: Highly related and with answers with more “modern” approaches: /questions/756166/rt3290-ralink-driver-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NOTE: The links referred to here may no longer operate.  They are left in here for historical purposes only.

- Download the source code of the driver:

  ```
  wget http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11876059/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508.tar.gz
  ```
- then extract the file from tar file

  ```
  tar -xvf DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508.tar.gz
  ```
- after that enter to this dir

  ```sh
  cd ~/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508
  make    
  # compile the make file
  sudo make install
  # install the make file
  ```
- After that activate the wireless driver

  ```
  sudo modprobe rt3290sta
  ```

Comment: I have used the script. I have now 16.04 and i got this error when enter the code "make":  :85: error: macro "__DATE__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]
 intf(extra, size, "Driver version-%s, %s %s\n", STA_DRIVER_VERSION, __DATE__, _
                                                                     ^
/home/ranjit/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux/../../sta/sta_cfg.c:4899:95: error: macro "__TIME__" might prevent reproducible builds [-Werror=date-time]

Comment: please enter this command  "lspci | grep Network" and give me the output  @Ranjit

Comment: 03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: this ans is for  Ralink RT3290.not for MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e.better way u post ur question and mention ur device name...thanks :)

Comment: ASUS X550C Laptop. and please let me know to enable my Wifi. I am in big trouble

Comment: @Ranjit follow the steps to install wifi driver here - http://askubuntu.com/questions/576854/wifi-not-working-in-asus-x550cc-on-ubuntu-14-04/763138#763138

Comment: If nothing else works see http://onthim.blogspot.co.ke/2015/06/install-ralink-rt3290-wi-fi-driver-on.html to download new drivers for the rt3290

Comment: link does not work

Comment: @user1993 send me your email id, I will send you by mail,

Comment: @SudipDas it's fine for me now, I solved the issue. I was just pointing out for the validity of the answer

Comment: guys.. why this zip is not available at any official site or repo?

Answer (score 10):

Since Ralink does not patch the driver and the current version does not work, I provided a patched file that you can download and install following this steps

1. [download the patched file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw6He1mvtZ9GSHRMYjhSeVhUMWc/view?usp=sharing) from my private Google Drive directory.
2. open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and `cd` into the folder where the file is downloaded, e.g. `cd ~/Downloads`.
3. type

   ```
   sudo tar -xvf rt3290sta-2.6.0.0.dkms.tar -C /usr/src
   ```

   to untar the content in a system directory
4. you should now get a password prompt where you type the `sudo` password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
5. once the files are all extracted type

   ```
   sudo dkms install -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 --force
   ```

   to install the driver with `dkms`
6. enter `sudo` password again and ensure that install is completed successfully (it will take some time).
7. reboot.
8. Enjoy Wi-Fi with your `RT3290` :D

The patch will work up to kernel version v4.14, it breaks on v4.15 onwards due to the change in the [kernel timer implementations](https://lwn.net/Articles/735887/).

Comment: I cannot believe that a private directory on Google Drive is the only source for that file - even with best intentions it can be dangerous to install it. Please provide a link to some official source.

Comment: Yea too bad ralink is not bothered to correct issues and only provides a 2 year old source. I've just removed a few errors from ralink's source. And just downloading the source will surely cause no harm. If you are so skeptical you could go through every line of it. peace

Comment: It is not about **me**. (1) This answer should be useful for a longer time. (2) we certainly don't expect every user to sift through 4.5 MB of source code (even if you patch consists of only 360 or so lines).

Comment: I've been searching for some official source for months now but as I said, no source has been released since Nov '13. So any user of the rt3290 wifi chip has 3 options. 1) Make his own patch. 2) Wait for ralink to patch the source (which, given the trend, might take forever). or 3) use the source I have provided in good faith. As u say, it's not about you or me. It's just a service that I have provided for free for the users of the chip. In future if this needs any modifications I'm sure quite a few in this community are capable of doing it. If you decide to wait for official source..good luck

Comment: Instead of using, sudo dkms install -m rt3290sta -v2.6.0.0 --force You need to put a space before 2.6.0.0 sudo dkms install -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 --force

Comment: does this driver also provide bluetooth support?

Comment: Any way I can revert this installation?

Comment: @ThomasSebastian, yes. You need to 1) remove the patched driver from your kernel: `sudo dkms remove rt3290sta/2.6.0.0 --all`; 2) remove the patched sources: `sudo rm -r /usr/src/rt3290sta-2.6.0.0`;  3) load the official driver instead of the patched one: `sudo rmmod rt3290sta` and `sudo modprobe rt2x00lib`. **DISCLAIMER**: not tested. The names might be slightly different. You should be able to reboot after the first two steps to make udev pick the official driver automagically.

Comment: Update: this driver didn't work for me on HP Envy 15-j151. `lshw` listed the wireless card as DISABLED no matter what. The uninstallation procedure I described above worked fine however, with the exception that I had to power-off for the official driver to take over.

Comment: I'm getting an error when I executed 5th stem in the mentioned answer. [This](https://image.ibb.co/ebz6hn/Screenshot_from_2018_03_03_06_40_05.png) is what I'm gettting