# WiFi issues with HP Pavilion g6 2312ax running Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, hp, wifi-hardware-switch

So I've been using Ubuntu for quite some time now. I've previously used Xubuntu 14.04. I've had problems with my WiFi adapter. My WiFi adapter seems to be disabled in Ubuntu. However, it seems to work just fine in Windows 8.1. I get the "Disabled by hardware switch" when I try to enable it. I've tried installing the drivers for my WiFi adapter (RT3290 802.11 b/g/n adapter + BT 4.0 combo).

I've tried the dkms method described here - [How to install wifi driver Ralink RT3290](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290) , and have come up with nothing. My WiFi adapter seems to be enabled, but it doesn't detect any networks.

P.S: Before you guys go all "Just press the Fn + F11" key, believe me, I've tried doing that like a hundred times. No result each time.

Also, my rfkill list all used to result in "Hard blocked: Yes" and "Soft blocked: no" until I used the method described in the link. It shows nothing now.

Can anyone help me out here ? I bought a new wireless router to use with my laptop and I really don't want it to go waste.

Pardon my english.

Answer (score 0):

Your wifi seems to be blocked, tru unblocking your device:
rfkill unblock (identifier)
It have to be unblocked to work.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. The rfkill list all doesn't give any output, so I can't use any identifier. However, I tried "rfkill unblock all" and that didn't fix anything.