# How to connect to WiFi and BlueTooth in Ubuntu 15.04?

Tags: connection-sharing

I just purchased an HP laptop 2 days ago with Windows 8.1 pre-installed. I formatted the OS and installed Ubuntu 15.04. The laptop seems to be working perfectly except two problems:

1. I am able to connect to the network via Ethernet but when I turn on WiFi the router device name shows up on screen and I click on it, it asks for the password.  Once I enter the password it doesn’t connect.
2. Even though my laptop is Bluetooth enabled when I go to the Bluetooth settings it shows up as `no Bluetooth adapter found`

*How should I proceed?*

This is what I got when I ran the `lspci` command.

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series SoC Transaction Register (rev 0e)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display (rev 0e)
00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 0f23 (rev 0e)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series USB xHCI (rev 0e)
00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Trusted Execution Engine (rev 0e)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio Controller (rev 0e)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0f48 (rev 0e)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0f4a (rev 0e)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0f4c (rev 0e)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0f4e (rev 0e)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Power Control Unit (rev 0e)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 0f12 (rev 0e)
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
02:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 07)
```

Comment: Firstly, THERE IS NO NEED FOR CAPSLOCK IN YOUR TITLE. (See how annoying it is?) Secondly, run `lspci` in the terminal and [edit] it into your question. _Don't_ just comment it, [edit] it in.

Comment: sorry. M new to this i hav no idea. Just used caps lock to highlight stuff. Hehe. My bad. Ill edit it in asap. Thanks for the help

Comment: And by edit it in do u mean that i should type the entire cli output that cmes.

Comment: Copy and paste it, yes. Then highlight it and press `ctrl` + `k` to put it in a code block.

Comment: sir but i am not able to paste the entire output. its showing that it is 722 characters long and is not posting the comment

Comment: Sorry. I was trying to add a codeblock to the comments. I have edited it into my question. Pls do check and help me. Studying MCA now and wanna learn ubuntu. Thanks in advance

Comment: Try this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290