# unstable wifi connection on 14.04LTC HP

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, internet

I have a 15-d051su Hp laptop, I just installed ubuntu 14.04 LTC and I am new to Linux. Everything is fine except the wifi. When I am using too much internet(downloading) after a couple of minutes my wifi connection crashes and the only way I can again get connected is to disable manualy wifi and enable it again and the process repeats after a couple of minutes.

I noticed that the more internet I use, the faster my connection crashes, also I found that if I download with a speed lower than the 100KB/s, my connection does not crash. Also if my connection does not crash at all if I have a wired connection.

The wifi works perfectly on windows

Wifi hardware info is:

```
       *-network
            description: Wireless interface
            product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
            vendor: Ralink corp.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
            logical name: wlan0
            version: 00
            serial: 9c:d2:1e:d2:e2:d3
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=3.19.0-42-generic firmware=0.37 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
            resources: irq:19 memory:90510000-9051ffff
```

[Wireless info script output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/14243256/)

Comment: Please help us help you by [edit]ing your question to include the output of `sudo lshw | grep -A13 network`

Comment: while on ethernet or with wifi ?

Comment: As it returns information about the hardware it shouldn't matter if you are connected to the internet at all when you run the command. Seeing as how your issue is with wifi it would seem logical to try it that way.

Comment: done, is this good enough ?

Comment: Thank you. I'm sure that will be helpful. I apologize for not sending you here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos first. The script in Wildman answer should provide all info required to assist in resolving your issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install wifi driver Ralink RT3290](http://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290)

Comment: Sorry i did not quite understand that last one, you want this link ? http://paste.ubuntu.com/14243256/

Comment: Yes. I'll add the link to your question.

Answer (score 0):

A number of Linux drivers seem to be sensitive to the access point to which they attach. First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo modprobe -r rt2800pci
sudo modprobe rt2800pci nohwcrypt=Y
```

If it helps, make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options rt2800pci nohwcrypt=Y"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/rt2800pci.conf
exit
```

Finally, Network Manager will default to ethernet if it's available. Please make your tests with the ethernet detached.

Comment: Isn't the rt3290sta driver a better choice given the hardware?

Comment: Well I did the things said in http://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290 and I think problem is resolved

Comment: @murloc Please upvote the solution there that worked for you once you are certain it's resolved so that others with the same problem can find the solution. Thank you!

Comment: actually, problem is not resolved but It crashes less now.