# My WIFI connection randomly drops

Tags: networking, wireless, network-manager, realtek-wireless

My Wifi connections randomly stops working. And the only way to "bring it back", without a click on wifi icon, is to open the terminal and type `sudo service network-manager restart` then it's reconnecting to (same) wifi access point, and it's working again till next time.

I know that it's not a problem in my Router/Wifi AP, because I am using 3 different computers, and on other 2 it's working fine.

What can I do ?

This is report of `sudo lshw -class network`

```
  *-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: ec:0e:c4:49:60:27
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.2.0-36-generic firmware=0.37 ip=192.168.1.104 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:17 memory:90710000-9071ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: 14:58:d0:c4:50:8d
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:263 ioport:1000(size=256) memory:90500000-90500fff memory:90400000-90403fff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue, but my wireless is Realtek rather that Ralink. Nonetheless the fix is pretty much the same, the problem is caused by a driver issue.

Please see the below for instruction on how to install your wifi drivers.

[How to install wifi driver Ralink RT3290](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290)

Comment: when I type sudo make install it gives me this error:
http://pastebin.com/5nyyPTsr

Comment: Just searched again and found the below. Looks like this one is more up to date and better maintained. Just make sure you go for the Ubuntu download.

http://onthim.blogspot.co.uk/2015/06/install-ralink-rt3290-wi-fi-driver-on.html

Comment: I installed, and everything was fine. Even my Wifi meter is now on 4 bars, before it was on 2 bars. But after I closed lid on my laptop,  it went into something called "Karnel Panic"(Capslock LED was flashing/blinking) and then I just leave him for about an hour and then it was fine. Now the connection is fine, exceept that it keep randomly disconnect me but now I just wait till it reconnects back and it's working again. Any fix for that ?