# Problem in the driver Ralink RT3290

Tags: wireless, ralink

I use Ubuntu 16.04. I've installed the driver Ralink RT3290. But I found this error which appears in my syslog file : "RT3290_AsicTxAlcGetAutoAgcOffset: Incorrect desired TSSI or current TSSI".

Has anyone any idea how to solve this problem and thanks!

Comment: Where did you find the driver exactly? That card has A LOT of problems with Ubuntu, and based on the driver you choose this problem might have different solutions.

Comment: I found this driver in this [link] (http://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290) I tried to use the first response, the selected one. But it dose not for me and I tried to use second one and it works for.

Comment: But so does it work or not?

Comment: It works ;) But I don't understand why I have such error. There are thousands of this error in mu **syslog** file

Comment: [TSSI is the Time Synchronization Service Interface](http://standards.ieee.org/findstds/standard/802.3bf-2011.html). That card doesn't work well with Linux, and this is a fact. Probably [it has some problems with some internal clock of the card](https://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse/2012-10/msg00203.html) that does not get handled properly. Since it works, and it is half a miracle that is does, I would personally not spend too much time trying to solve it, since it will probably break something else in the driver...

Comment: Thanks @dadexix86 ! I'd like to know if that drive could cause any problem to my card !

Comment: Well, since it is not an official driver, but it is open source, either you ask to the person who built and shared it in the first place (and you trust her/him), or you go through the source code yourself and look for malicious code. I don't have the competences to do the second task for you.