# Not getting wifi after updated to 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, 16.04, ralink, hp-pavilion

I just got updated to ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04. There is no wifi option.
Laptop is HP pavilion g6. Driver is ralink .ifconfig only showing eth0 and lo

Comment: Please open a terminal and run: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2` Find out what the actual driver is and try to load it: `sudo modprobe <whatever_driver>` Any errors or warnings? Also, confirm that the wireless switch or key combination is set to ENable wireless: `rfkill list all`

Comment: You're probably using DKMS for the Ralink driver. In 16.04 all drivers now need to be "signed", and your driver is not. Go to your BIOS and turn off SECURE BOOT and you should probably be ok.

Comment: i found it myself and its working well

Answer (score 0):

[How to install wifi driver Ralink RT3290](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290][how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290])
click this link for install the drivers.

Then type in the terminal with out the quotes.
"sudo ifconfig eno1 up" and 
"sudo service network-manager restart"