# Wireless "device not ready" after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: wireless

I have upgraded to Lubuntu 16.04 and the wireless does not work. It worked in 14.04.

```
lspci | grep Wireless
09:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
```

In NM both Enable Networking and Enable Wireless are checked, but it reads: Wi-fi networks / Device not ready.

```
rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I have run wireless-info, the results are in http://paste.ubuntu.com/23061345/

I have also edited /etc/NetworkManage/NetworkManager.conf, setting managed to true

```
[ifupdown]
managed=true
```

I have a sense that all I have to do is to unload a wrong module and to load the right one, but I am a bit disoriented about this. Can anyone help?

*EDIT*

I am truly unwilling to add this as an answer because the procedure is totally crazy, so I just edit the question. I even more hope that someone can explain what happened. The wireless is now working -- I am actually using it now. I specify what I have done step by step.

- Since the wireless worked in 14.04, I made a **live usb of Lubuntu 14.04.3**. My plan was to launch wireless-info from there, then to compare its output with the 16.04 version. I used a  newly formatted usb drive -- no persistence, the very option has disappeared from the 16.04 version of Startup Disc Creator.
- **Switch off** the PC, **switch on** with usb drive in place.
- Ubuntu starts and loads **the new version**, that is 16.04, even if the usb drive continually flashes. The wireless doesn't work. The filesystem that appears in PcManFM is the one on my HDD, not the one in the usb drive. The usb drive is invisible in PcManFM.
- Shutdown, plug out usb drive, switch on.
- Lubuntu 16.04 starts and **the wireless works perfectly**. Check the usb drive with gparted: it reports an unrecognized file system. I delete the partition, format the usb drive for data, check and re-check its integrity; it's ok.

This is surely weird. Some malfunctioning in Startup Drive Creator repaired a malfunctioning with the wireless. I'd by no means recommend this as a solution, not even a heuristic one. The only sensible thing I can do is to paste the URL of the new wireless-info text:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/23061620/

The comparison is striking. The same modules, with the same parameters. But, in the working case, wlan0 is given an inet address whereas in the non-working case the address is for eth0. But the reason for this is, to me, entirely obscure. Perhaps one should unplug the ethernet cable before starting the pc?

((Offtopic as this might be, I suggest that serious attention should also be given to the fact that Startup Disc Creator produces usb keys that somehow tinker with the OS.))

Comment: Also see http://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290