# Wifi not working after switching off with button after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: wireless, 16.04, hp, button

I just upgraded from 14.40 to 16.04 on an HP 250 G3. Everything worked fine until i hit the f12 button which is for switching wifi on and off on this machine. It doesn't turn on anymore. What could be the problem?

I trid `rfkill unblock all` as in this thread https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1768398 but now it's written device not ready under the wifi icon.

`rfkill list all`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

`lsmod | grep -e wmi -e lap`:

```
hp_wmi                 16384  0
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd                    81920  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
sparse_keymap          16384  2 hp_wmi,intel_hid
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
```

The result of `dmesg | grep rt2` can be found [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23138543/)

The result of `rfkill list all` is

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

i tried to install drivers as [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290) in second answer step 1 to 8 but i got

```
directory "/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-36-generic"
```

Makefile:380: set of instructions for target "LINUX" failed
make: *** [LINUX] Errore 2

```
iwconfig

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=0 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

enp8s0    no wireless extensions.


 ifconfig

enp8s0    Link encap:Ethernet  IndirizzoHW ec:b1:d7:c0:d7:ce  
          indirizzo inet:192.168.1.3  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Maschera:255.255.255.0
          indirizzo inet6: fe80::e232:848d:e380:c3de/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:9232 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:7727 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          Byte RX:5761975 (5.7 MB)  Byte TX:2176773 (2.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Loopback locale  
          indirizzo inet:127.0.0.1  Maschera:255.0.0.0
          indirizzo inet6: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1063 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1063 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisioni:0 txqueuelen:1 
          Byte RX:93916 (93.9 KB)  Byte TX:93916 (93.9 KB)
```

result of `dmesg | grep rt2`:
paste.ubuntu.com/23138711

Comment: Iy does turn on again but you have to wait up to a minute to see the networks again.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and also: `lsmod | grep -e wmi -e lap` Welsome to askubuntu.

Comment: Thank you @chili555! @CelticWarrior i can confirm it doesn't.

Comment: Your readings above all look perfectly normal and not blocked. Perhaps the driver isn't loaded. Also add: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`

Comment: What is the exact result of the terminal command: `sudo modprobe rt2800pci`  ?

Comment: The result is null

Comment: But then did the wireless spring to life?

Comment: he wireless didnt turn on - device not ready

Comment: Please run: `dmesg | grep rt2` As the result will be lengthy, paste the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com Also, is there any change in: `rfkill list all`  ?

Comment: I added the results and tried to install drivers but itwont go on

Comment: Please edit to include results for `iwconfig; ifconfig`

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this error before:

> rt2800_wait_wpdma_ready: Error - WPDMA TX/RX busy

Please see: https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/506888-OpenSUSE-13-1-wireless-problem-with-firmware-Ralink-RT3290-(kernel-4-0-0-1-1-g49e42b3-x86_64)

In the post I linked, it says:

> While I was waiting for answers I did recall reading someone in these
>   forums suggesting to remove 802.11n from the router .
>
> So I tested that today it it worked.
>
> That is, I set the router to broadcast only 802.11g. ( Previously
>   802.11n was among the protocols it broadcasted.)
>
> And it WORKED. wlan has been on since this morning with no glitch.

Also see: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2334099

> YES!! I removed 802.11n, leaving both "b" and "g" on, and it works!! 
>   thank you very much!!

Please change the setting on your router to use 802.11B and G only and not N. Reboot the router and see if you connect.

Comment: I did the thing on the router and rebooted but nothing happened

Comment: Please reboot the computer and run: `dmesg | grep rt2` and paste again. Please give us the link.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23138711/

Comment: May I also see a paste of: `sudo iwlist wlo1 scan` Only paste your own network; not your neighbors.