# Permanently enable Wifi in 16.04

Tags: networking, wireless, ralink

I have a Ralink RT3290, which does not have a built-in driver in 16.04, but I installed one following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/557427/308164).

At every login, wifi is not enabled. I can enable it by running:

```
sudo ifconfig rename3 up
sudo service network-manager restart
```

after which it works fine (`rename3` is the logical name of the device, no idea why).

**How can I enable wifi by default, so I do not need to type this at every login?** (An *ad-hoc* script at start is not what I am looking for)

**EDIT:** In [this link](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23477084/) there is all the relevant information, as suggested by chili555 in a comment.

Comment: "...which does not have a built-in driver in 16.04..." I believe it does, *rt2800pci*. It may take some tweaking to work, however.

Comment: But is it installed by default? Why it was not working in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about the driver rt3290sta except, from working with it over the years, I know that it's getting a bit old. The fact that the interface appears as 'rename3' suggests that it's an unhappy driver. I would much rather tweak some settings and get the default driver rt2800pci working well.

Please open a terminal and do:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ralink.conf
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit. Change the file to read:

```
#blacklist rt2800pci
#blacklist rt2x00pci
blacklist rt3290sta
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor. Then set your regulatory domain explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Finally, the default driver, rt2800pci, seems to be troubled by 802.11N. If your router is capable of it, I suggest that you switch from mixed 802.11B, G and N to B and G only.

I also notice this:

```
Channel occupancy:
  5   APs on   Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
  2   APs on   Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
  8   APs on   Frequency:2.462 GHz (Channel 11)
```

Your router is on the very crowded channel 1. I suggest you change to channel 6.

Reboot the computer and the router and let us hear your report. I will edit my answer as needed to add further troubleshooting steps.

Comment: Changed channel and network. Works fine now!

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working.