# WIFI interface disappeared

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm here because today, suddenly, the network interface no longer appears.  When I try `ifconfig -a`, I get:

```
juanch0x@Juan-Notebook:~$ sudo ifconfig -a
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  direcciÃ³nHW 38:ea:a7:f6:d7:1a  
          ACTIVO DIFUSIÃ“N MULTICAST  MTU:1500  MÃ©trica:1
          Paquetes RX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:0 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1000 
          Bytes RX:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Bucle local  
          Direc. inet:127.0.0.1  MÃ¡sc:255.0.0.0
          DirecciÃ³n inet6: ::1/128 Alcance:AnfitriÃ³n
          ACTIVO BUCLE FUNCIONANDO  MTU:65536  MÃ©trica:1
          Paquetes RX:23231 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          Paquetes TX:23231 errores:0 perdidos:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          colisiones:0 long.colaTX:1 
          Bytes RX:2839707 (2.8 MB)  TX bytes:2839707 (2.8 MB)
```

Before this happened I had other network called "rename3".
**EDIT:**
Last time it works was before download the automatic updates from ubuntu

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
```

Result

```
juanch0x@Juan-Notebook:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    DeviceName: Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi Adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter [103c:18ec]
```

**SOLVED**

I solved the problem reinstalling the drivers, for some reason, when i used the automatic updates, it was deleted, that was the reason of all this problem

Thanks **Celtic Warrior** for your help!

Comment: What happened right before the network "disappeared"? Please edit and post the result of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2`.

Comment: Thanks CelticWarrior, i added the log you ask, and the last thing i was do before the network disappeared was download the automatic updates from ubuntu

Comment: This may help: http://askubuntu.com/a/849772/589808 (the very last part is specific for the other user's situation).

Comment: I was having the same problem as that guy, but now directly rename3 doesn't appear, what part do you say i must try?

Comment: Everything up to "I also notice this".

Comment: I do it work for one reboot, then doesn't work anymore, but now i get a new interface (wlo1), but the problem is when i want to do sudo ifconfig wlo1 up, i get the error "SIOCSIFFLAGS: Error de entrada/salida", do you have some idea why that could happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install custom kernel modules from source, you need to re-install them every time the kernel is upgraded.

To avoid it, you can install the driver using DKMS.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and not even a reinstall of Ubuntu fixed it. What did fix it was turning off the pc, cutting power to it and leaving it for a few minutes (pressing the Power button while there is no power to it will also deplete any remaining electrical charge in the power supply). Then the wireless interface came back after starting it again. I didn't even have to reinstall.