# Airplane mode switch does not respond

Tags: airplane-mode

HP Envy 15 x360 PC running Ubuntu 17.10 shows airplane mode ON and grayed out despite all the efforts.

(<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f12</kbd>) does not work.

Wifi/bluetooth are off and cannot be switched on using menus.

More details:

```
se@se-hp:~$ nmcli radio wifi on

se@se-hp:~$  rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 [8086:08b1] (rev c3)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-AC 7260 [8086:4070]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi

ls /lib/firmware/*7260*
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode  /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode 
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-17.ucode
```

[image: BIOS photo]

Comment: Is `Fn+F10` the correct combination? They are very system specific. Can you check the marking on the keyboard and make sure you are pressing the right ones?

Comment: Otherwise you'll have to check out the networking and wireless options in the BIOS. It might have been disabled there

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: Added the lspci output. Thank you for responding.

Comment: *Wireless "option" in BIOS does exist but it is grayed out* This suggests an hardware problem. An Intel 7260 should just work.

Comment: F12 (not F10 - my typo) has little airplane image on it. All F buttons use Fn - as set in BIOS. Wireless "option" in BIOS does exist but it is grayed out. Wired connection works fine. Same issue with Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: I added the image of BIOS screen which contains a grayed line WLAN FCC ID. It does not look like an option, so I used quotations. It had been like this under Windows too, when Windows existed on this computer.

Comment: sigh... The first BIOS/UEFI page is usually FYI only (except time/date). You may or may not have other settings for enabling/disabling onboard devices but certainly NOT in "main".

Comment: You should use TAB key in that BIOS screen to navigate to other tabs where you can actually change the settings. As @MichaelBay has mentioned, you are just in the read only tab.

Comment: As the level of navigating though BIOS tabs there is nothing else on wireless or bluetooth. On this computer it is arrows, not tabs.

Answer (score 1):

My new HP computer also had some problems with wi-fi under Ubuntu. Slightly different model and problems, and I managed to fix the most of them, though.

I'm using an HP 15-bs048ns. Maybe you can try these methods, ordered by increasing desperation ‒ hope it helps.

(Please excuse me if you already tried some of them or they're really obvious. I don't know how knowledgeable are you at Linux, and it could help other users out there. I'll try to add links to related answers and pages, too.)

### Try not holding the Fn key

You probably have already tried this, but, is your airplane key Fn + F12 or just F12? Some laptops, by default, require that you hold Fn for the F1...F12 keys **and not** for the special keys.

In my laptop, F12 is airplane, and Fn+F12 is F12. You can set your Fn key to work the traditional way from the BIOS, though. (F12 = F12, Fn+F12 = airplane)

(No matter what the setting, modifier keys work normally with function keys: Shift+F10 will never press the Play/Pause key.)

### Airplane key won't work in a GUI - try from the text console

I have an airplane key in F12, but for some reason, it doesn't work under X or Wayland. But it works from the text console (TTY)

If I want to use the Airplane key, I need to:

- Press Ctrl+Alt+F3 (no need to worry for the Fn key).
- Type my username and password
- Press the Airplane key
- Press Ctrl+Alt+F2 to return to the GUI.

If my keyboard shortcuts to move between the TTY and the GUI don't work, just try different function keys (F1, F2... through F7)

### Install a different module for your wi-fi

My computer didn't even have drivers for my wireless. Yours appears to, but they might not be working properly.

If you need to install new drivers, you'll need first to disable the Secure Boot in [shim](https://askubuntu.com/questions/342365/what-is-the-difference-between-grubx64-and-shimx64):

```
sudo mokutil --disable-validation
```

It will ask you for a one-time password. Don't bother using a good one, it only works until the next reboot.

You reboot, and when you encounter a blue screen reading “Press any KEY to perform MOK management”, press a key and follow the instructions. You'll probably need to type three separate characters from the password, suppose you used `abcdefgh` as password:

```
Type character 4 of password: d
Type character 8 of password: h
Type character 1 of password: a
```

Press Enter after every letter. Yes, these instructions look too detailed, but it's pretty common to screw up the first time (I did).

I don't know where you can find better modules for your computer. Mine works with [lwfinger's drivers](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new) **(my problems were only with the wi-fi; you'll probably need modules for both bluetooth and wifi)**.

In any case, if you find your module, it needs to be recompiled every time you upgrade the kernel (or else, the wireless interface and the wireless menus at Ubuntu [disappear](https://askubuntu.com/questions/883767/wifi-interface-disappeared) on your next boot.). You can [set up DKMS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DKMS) to recompile them automatically every kernel upgrade ‒ I'm still testing this so I can't give you detailed instructions.

### Reprogram your keyboard

I read somewhere (I'll link it if I find it) I could use the `showkey` command under the TTY to read key events straight from the kernel. And `showkey -s` to find the address of the pressed key.

Looking at the showkey man page, it doesn't directly read them from the kernel anymore, and the airplane key doesn't output any key event for me... even though it clearly works.

But my computer manages its wireless differently (I'm not sure I even have a hard lock), so it might work for you. If it sends **some** key event, you can reprogram the key to a different function ― maybe it will work.

You can read at the [answer NicoTho that posted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/965595/why-does-airplane-mode-keep-toggling-on-my-hp-laptop-in-ubuntu-17-10) how to reprogram a key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I figured out that my airplane key won't work in a GUI. Do you know of a fix?

Comment: Use the newer systemd script option I have detailed here, it got my airplane mode key finally working again: https://askubuntu.com/questions/965595/