# ralink rt5390 wifi drivers errors

Tags: drivers, wireless, ralink

So i've been trying to install the drivers with this strings answers and methods [How to install wifi driver Ralink RT3290](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290/593018#593018?newreg=ba6d38e0d65f4a5caa397117b48f807f)
and when im entering the command

```
cd ~/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508
make    
# compile the make file
sudo make install
# install the make file
```

it gives me this

```
install: cannot stat 'rt3290sta.ko': No such file or directory
Makefile.6:255: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mr-dickson/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux'
Makefile:473: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

i have the files extracted and unextracted in my home and downloads folder and i have even taken all the files from the folder and extracted them straight in both categories with them being out of the folder... also seen 6 or 7 other sites and ways and always getting erors, pls need help, im new with linux/ubuntu

Comment: It is doubtful that installing a circa-2012 (read:OLD!) driver will be better than the built-in driver rt2800pci. Please tell us what problem you are having and we'll be happy to help.

Comment: @chili555 Meh, nvm i just set up my 30M long enthernet wire, if i ever feel like i need the wifi i'll prob just install win10 as i have more experience and see it more benefitical for my use, ps the email notification dosent apparently work :/