# wifi problem rt3290 16.04 disabled

Tags: 16.04, ralink, ifconfig

i have the same problem, in ifconfig i put my first installation it was recognised. then i lost the installation. now shows only ethernet and other stuff. I see the link like listed. but is not enabled from the logical part where I could connect to any ssid.

Comment: abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for abcdef: 
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: rename3
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN latency=0

Comment: abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

rename3   Ralink STA  
          
abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: as you can see under this text. it s not listed in the ifconfig

Comment: abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$ ifconfig
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:d3:c1:63:0d:0d  
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
        

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          
abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~$

Comment: Did you check 'dmesg' for any kernel related output? Maybe the Realtek driver is not installed or enabled.

Comment: no error from dmesg

Comment: well actually i found this one

Comment: https://justpaste.it/11nc0

Comment: Okay, seems broken driver. Try reinstalling the driver from Ubuntu Repo.

Comment: please any hints for this ? is there a removal process to work on ?

Comment: i tried these two techniques. the first one worked and came live a short time and disaeppeared. http://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290

Comment: Hope this helps http://askubuntu.com/a/557427/519116.  Lastly, if needed 'sudo modprobe rt3290sta'

Comment: abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads$ sudo dkms install -m rt3290sta -v 2.6.0.0 --force
Module rt3290sta/2.6.0.0 already installed on kernel 4.4.0-57-generic/x86_64
abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads$

Comment: I have both solutions installed. how do i remove the first one ?

Comment: Did you try 'sudo modprobe rt3290sta' ?

Comment: yes tried that long time ago. now uninstalling it. the modprobe does not affect in anyhow...

Comment: abcdef@abcdef-HP-Pavilion-17-Notebook-PC:~/Downloads$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface

Comment: Now it is beyond my scope. Hope someone can carry it forward. Sorry brother.

Comment: both are uninstalled. thank you dear friend !!

Comment: think will go to mint for better hw support. it s a hell this stuff.

Comment: No comments friend :)