# Ralink RT3290 Wireless Drops/Doesn't Show Up Ubuntu 16.04.2

Tags: 16.04, drivers, ralink

I know a lot of people asked this question.

I tried [How to install wifi driver Ralink RT3290](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290)
and also http://onthim.blogspot.se/2015/06/install-ralink-rt3290-wi-fi-driver-on.html

Both of them worked. I was happy with the driver i put up in the first link but it suddenly started to drop even though my router is right next to my desk. This happens mostly when I'm using my laptop in battery mode.

Then I removed the driver and installed the driver i put up in the second link. It worked flawlessly until I upgraded to a newer kernel. I had to reinstall those drivers from the beginning. It is so annoying that every time I switch on my laptop, I have to reinstall it. :/

I know I'm asking a lot but if somebody could link me up with a permanent fix, I'll be really grateful. I'm just a newbie so I clearly have no idea what else to do. 
Thanks.

**EDITED : Wifi works well in Ubuntu 17.10** cheers :)

Comment: DKMS can be installed on your system and used to auto-magically recompile/reinstall drivers during a kernel upgrade. If you can find a driver with "dkms" in its filename, you'll have everything you need. Otherwise you'll need to write a tiny dkms.conf file yourself. Check https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=RT3290&type=

Comment: ps: or https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=RT3290sta&type=

Comment: ps2: the first driver probably had power management turned on for the RT3290, and that's why it dropped connection when on battery. A simple command to disable power management, so you might try it again, esp if it has a dkms.conf file already.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks. I tried that but now i have an issue where it says firmware is missing. I guess that's because of the patched driver which removes any conflicting drivers from the kernel. So I had to reinstall that second driver I linked up in the question to make it work again. 
I will try it once again with a fresh install of ubuntu/linux mint. Thank you.

Comment: There are normally 3-4 firmware files pre-installed in your system. The system... for example... tries to load version 18, and if it doesn't find it, tries to load version 17, etc until it finds a version that is there. Recheck your syslog and I think you'll find that microcode did get loaded. Normally patched drivers don't **remove** old drivers, but sometimes they rename them to *.bak. But if that were the case, the wireless wouldn't work at all.

Comment: @heynnema I'm still a newbie so thanks for pointing that out. I really appreciate your help :)