# WiFi disabled after everytime I boot Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, network-manager

I did already post this question yesterday, but since I got no replies, I'm asking it again. Really hoping, you guys would be able to help me.

I'm a new Ubuntu user and have been using it just for the past 2 days. I saw that my wifi strength is much superior in windows than in Ubuntu. So, I thought of updating the wireless driver in Ubuntu.
I am having a problem that my network is disabled after boot. I'm currently running dual boot with Windows 8.1.
Here's the output of `sudo lshw -C network` :

```
*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 07
       serial: 38:63:bb:72:97:97
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b5600000-b5600fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff
  *-network DISABLED
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA
       resources: irq:16 memory:b5510000-b551ffff
```

After I boot, I need to run these 2 commands:

```
sudo ifconfig eno1 up 
sudo service network-manager restart
```

It's really frustrating, that I need to run these 2 commands, everytime I boot my laptop. It started happening after I installed the rt3290 drivers as mentioned here https://askubuntu.com/a/593018/692756

After the commands, here's the output of `sudo lshw -C network` :

```
*-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 07
       serial: 38:63:bb:72:97:97
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:41 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b5600000-b5600fff memory:b5400000-b5403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0a:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 00
       serial: c0:38:96:6e:ae:d7
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN ip=192.168.225.110 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA
       resources: irq:16 memory:b5510000-b551ffff
```

Here's the output of `iwconfig`:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

eno1      Ralink STA  ESSID:"BAZINGA"  Nickname:"RT3290STA"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency=2.422 GHz  Access Point: 18:A6:F7:EA:2C:64   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   
          RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level:-52 dBm  Noise level:-84 dBm
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

enp8s0    no wireless extensions.
```

The power management is not being shown, but I'm sure it's disabled, because the value of `wifi.powersave = 2` in my `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` file.

Comment: I wonder if the wireless card is blocked. At a command line try sudo rfkill unblock all. It's just a guess, something simple to eliminate.

Comment: `rfkill unblock all` doesn't do anything. It returned a blank output. I needed to enable my interface `eno1` and then restart network-manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of tries, installing wicd, uninstalling network-manager and then reverting back, I changed the `/etc/rc.local` file.
I added 
`sudo ifconfig eno1 up` 
 `sudo service network-manager restart` 
 before the `exit 0` statement. What it basically does is, whenever the system changes its runlevel, that is shutdown, rebooting, or interchanging between multilevel and single user, the scripts are executed. So, I do not need to type it every time I booted, the rc.local file did it for me. I still don't know why it happened, but at least it's working.

Answer (score 3):

So I've had a similiar problem but

```
sudo ifconfig <wifi logical name> up
sudo service network-manager restart
```

didn't fix my problem as rfkill had the wifi hard-blocked.

My solution - which may still help you though - was to edit the blacklist with:

`sudo vim /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

adding the line(s):

```
blacklist wmi
blacklist asus_wmi
blacklist asus_nb_wmi
```

wmi (windows management instrumentation)  often affects dual boot systems and may be disabling your wifi. Use

`lsmod | grep wmi`

to check what wmi modules are currently running on your system and then use blacklist to disable them. Worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

This might be caused by wireless power management messing with the kernel module.  Wireless power management can be disabled with

```
sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf
systemctl restart network-manager.service
```

I would also uninstall that module you got from github

```
cd ~/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508
sudo make uninstall
```

Along with the one you installed from the UbuntuForums post

```
cd ~/RT3290_u16
sudo ./uninstall.sh
sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rt2800pci.conf
```

Reboot

Comment: I've edited my question. My power management is off, but somehow it's not being shown in the `iwconfig` command.

Comment: I didn't try your edited comment. I found a workaround. Thanks for your help.