# Problem with RT3290 wifi driver on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless

I am experiencing problems with wifi on newly installed ubuntu 16.04.

For this reason I have followed steps described in [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290#answer-557427) answer. 

However now the wifi connections completely disappeared from networks. 

How can I fix this?

I have tried to do

```
sudo ifconfig eno1 up
sudo service network-manager restart
```

But nothing changes

Outputs from commands:

**ifconfig**

```
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 38:ea:a7:f4:bd:e4  
      UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:14517 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:14517 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:782728 (782.7 KB)  TX bytes:782728 (782.7 KB)
```

**lsmod**

```
    Module                  Size  Used by
rndis_host             16384  0
cdc_ether              16384  1 rndis_host
usbnet                 45056  2 rndis_host,cdc_ether
cfg80211              565248  0
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
kvm_intel             172032  0
kvm                   544768  1 kvm_intel
hp_wmi                 16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
uvcvideo               90112  0
snd_hda_codec_idt      57344  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_idt
snd_hda_intel          40960  3
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
aesni_intel           167936  0
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0
snd                    81920  17 snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
lpc_ich                24576  0
hp_accel               28672  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
mei_me                 36864  0
lis3lv02d              20480  1 hp_accel
soundcore              16384  1 snd
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
input_polldev          16384  1 lis3lv02d
input_leds             16384  0
joydev                 20480  0
rt3290sta            1155072  0
serio_raw              16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
hp_wireless            16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0
amdkfd                131072  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
radeon               1515520  1
i915                 1208320  3
ttm                    98304  1 radeon
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,radeon
drm_kms_helper        155648  2 i915,radeon
psmouse               131072  0
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
rtsx_pci               53248  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
ahci                   36864  2
libahci                32768  1 ahci
r8169                  81920  0
drm                   364544  8 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,radeon
mii                    16384  2 r8169,usbnet
wmi                    20480  1 hp_wmi
video                  40960  1 i915
fjes                   28672  0
```

**sudo lshw -class network**

```
*-network DISABLED      
       description: Wireless interface
       product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
       vendor: Ralink corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: rename3
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=RALINK WLAN latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=Ralink STA
       resources: irq:16 memory:63510000-6351ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: eno1
       version: 05
       serial: 38:ea:a7:f4:bd:e4
       size: 10Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8105e-1.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
       resources: irq:26 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:63404000-63404fff memory:63400000-63403fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp0s20u1
       serial: 02:1b:0a:0d:0f:7b
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.195 link=yes multicast=yes
```

**lspci**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)
07:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
07:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. RT3290 Bluetooth
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)
09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5229 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please post results for `rfkill list` Thanks

Comment: i have noticed that my network adapter was disabled and I don't know why the configuration had a title of 'rename3'. Running 
`sudo ifconfig rename3 up`
`sudo service network-manager restart`
have solved the problem