# RT5390 WiFi Card Suddenly Stopped Working Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, ralink

Spent a few hours on this one and it's driving me crazy. My dad has been running Ubuntu 14.04, 16.04 and now 18.04 on his laptop for ages and had no issues with the RT5390 WiFi Adapter.

It was working in 18.04 just fine and then nothing.
It doesn't appear in the output of `lshw -C network`, just the Ethernet card.

```
*-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0.2
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.2
   logical name: eno1
   version: 0a
   serial: 84:34:97:19:d3:89
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8411-1_0.0.3 06/18/12 ip=192.168.2.69 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:26 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:c0404000-c0404fff memory:c0400000-c0403fff
```

Same thing for the output of `lspci -nnk | grep net -iA3`

```
01:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:18a4]
Kernel driver in use: r8169
Kernel modules: r8169
```

Tried building this module but got failures in the `make` step: https://github.com/agerwick/RT28XX-RT539X-Linux-driver

Tried running both answers from this section even though it's horribly insecure.
[How to install wifi driver Ralink RT3290](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290)

Any ideas? Could this be an actual hardware failure since it happened so suddenly? Thanks.

EDIT: As requested here's an output of just `lspci -nnk`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [8086:0154] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller [103c:18a4]
    Kernel driver in use: ivb_uncore
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [103c:18a4]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [8086:1e31] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller [103c:18a4]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 [8086:1e3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller [103c:18a4]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 [8086:1e2d] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [103c:18a4]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:1e20] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller [103c:18a4]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:1e10] (rev c4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
    Kernel modules: shpchp
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 [8086:1e26] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller [103c:18a4]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [8086:1e57] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company HM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller [103c:18a4]
    Kernel modules: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller [0104]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] [8086:282a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] [103c:18a4]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
    Kernel modules: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [8086:1e22] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller [103c:18a4]
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5289] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8411 PCI Express Card Reader [103c:18a4]
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci
01:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [103c:18a4]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
    Kernel modules: r8169
```

Comment: "Could this be an actual hardware failure since it happened so suddenly? " Possibly. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks Chili, added the output. Doesnt appear to be there either.

Comment: You might double-check the BIOS to see if there is any setting to enable/disable wireless. You might also try reseating the card in its PCI slot. Finally, there are many fully supported USB wireless devices available for US$15-20. Sorry.

Comment: I'll look for that but didn't see it. Someone mentioned turning off Secure Boot so I tried that to no success. Any suggestions for replacement PCI WiFi cards? Intel? Atheros?

Comment: Product recommendations are Intel frowned upon Intel here at AU.