# Wifi disconnects abruptly and frequently

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, ralink

Wifi disables abruptly. Tried the solution available on the internet.None worked.Need to disable and enable wifi to start the connection. Cant upgrade to Ubuntu 18.04 as download stops due to wifi issue.Need help.

output after running `lspci` command:

```
$ lspci -knn | grep -i net -A3
02:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12) 
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:200f] 
        Kernel driver in use: r8169 
        Kernel modules: r8169 
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290] 
        Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [105b:e055] 
        Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci 
        Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

Comment: Add the output of  `lspci -knn | grep -i net -A3`

Comment: 02:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1043:200f]
 Kernel driver in use: r8169
 Kernel modules: r8169
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
 Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [105b:e055]
 Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
 Kernel modules: rt2800pci

Comment: take a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290 https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058504/ralink-rt3290-wifi-problem

Comment: Mirror for RaLink RT3290 WiFi Driver for Ubuntu based distr https://github.com/pkeeper/rt3290sta

Answer (score 0):

### [Installation of Ralink RT3290](https://github.com/pkeeper/rt3290sta)

- fork this repo
- cd into it
- compile the driver
- install the driver

comand for that (it will ask your user password to apply changes to system):

```
git clone https://github.com/pkeeper/rt3290sta.git
cd rt3290sta 
make  
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r rt2800pci 
sudo modprobe rt3290sta
```

Now you need to make it load on startup. Blacklist the `rt2800pci` driver in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf` and add `rt3290sta` to `/etc/modules`.