# RT3290/RTL810xE Wi-Fi very weak

Tags: networking, drivers, lubuntu

I use Lubuntu 20.04

This was the best solution I could find but apparently it doesn't work because of my kernel [The solution  I m talking about](https://askubuntu.com/a/557427/1097343)

Please Help me I don't want to go back to windows :(

[sudo lshw -C network](https://pastebin.com/qXcQCQdC)

[lspci -v | grep -A20 Ethernet](https://pastebin.com/bUFXq2uy)

[lsmod](https://pastebin.com/23x7eiEm)

[lspci -nn](https://pastebin.com/J94f5N0Y)

Comment: Just week. It disconnects frequently, I have to reboot my notebook to be able to use the internet and I'm like 2m away from my WiFi.

Comment: See chili555's answer to https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2342997 for some checking/diagnostics, particularly the modinfo output for your module, will give some indication of the options available.

Comment: I didn't really understand what you mean by that, but the only thing I could change from that post was about my ISO 3166. which I set to my country. :/

Answer (score 1):

Your paste shows that your router is on channel 10. I suspect that indicates that the router is set to autoselect the channel, as channel 10 is not usually set explcitly as it is an overlapped channel: https://www.metageek.com/training/resources/why-channels-1-6-11.html

I suggest that you change the router to use a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11 as the link recommends.

Next, WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed or autoselect mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds.

Your paste also shows the router as:

```
Quality=48/70  Signal level=-62 dBm
```

This weak symptom may actually be the fault of the router. Please check to see if there is a setting in the router for TX power:

[image]

If so, please try increasing it.

Finally, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save (Ctrl+o followed by Enter) and close (Ctrl+x) the text editor.

Comment: My router only has WPA/PSK and WPA2/PSK and the both together which is the default option what should I change too. I did changed to 11 and it doesn't seem to had any kinda of effect, and my transmission power is already on high so Im good there.
I sucefully changed the Regdomain to my country (Brazil).
Did everything, reset my computer and still nothing. I have a windows 10 with dual bot and there my internet signal is much better. And the downloads too runs ok there but not on Lubuntu. Also on windows 10 it doesn't disconnect every hour like on lubuntu.
This WiFi thing is the only problem

Comment: Please set the router to WPA2/PSK *only* and not any mixed mode. Please report back.