# Bluetooth error in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, bluetooth, bluez

**Hello**
I am trying to make my adapter discoverable but it displays me this:- after `bluetoothctl`

```
[bluetooth]# scan on
[bluetooth]# discoverable on
Changing discoverable on succeeded
[bluetooth]# scan on
Failed to start discovery: org.bluez.Error.InProgress
[bluetooth]#
```

Output of command :- `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [105b:e055]
    Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
    Kernel modules: rt2800pci
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2883 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Output of command :-`dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`

```
   [   12.851854] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
    [   12.851883] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
    [   12.851888] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
    [   12.851889] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
    [   12.851893] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
    [   67.399550] audit: type=1400 audit(1611909043.091:58): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=875 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
    [   67.727240] audit: type=1400 audit(1611909043.419:60): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=875 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [   67.929889] audit: type=1400 audit(1611909043.619:62): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=1043 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
    [   67.930261] audit: type=1400 audit(1611909043.623:63): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1043 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [   68.194380] audit: type=1400 audit(1611909043.887:65): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" pid=1102 comm="bluetoothd" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
    [   68.194710] audit: type=1400 audit(1611909043.887:66): apparmor="DENIED" operation="connect" profile="snap.bluez.bluez" name="/run/dbus/system_bus_socket" pid=1102 comm="bluetoothd" requested_mask="wr" denied_mask="wr" fsuid=0 ouid=0
    [   81.668783] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
    [   81.668785] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
    [   81.668791] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
    [ 1965.556683] Bluetooth: RTBT_Tb: vendor=0x1814, device=0x3298
    [ 1965.556685] Bluetooth: RTBT_Tb: vendor=0x0, device=0x0
    [ 1965.556687] Bluetooth: DynamicAlloc pci_device_id table at 0x00000000ad8b89c2 with size 64
    [ 1965.556688] Bluetooth: RTBT_Tb: vendor=0x1814, device=0x3298
    [ 1965.556689] Bluetooth: Convert: vendor=0x1814, device=0x3298
    [ 1965.556690] Bluetooth: RTBT_Tb: vendor=0x0, device=0x0
    [ 1965.556691] Bluetooth: pci_device_id: vendor=0x1814, device=0x3298
    [ 1965.556922] Bluetooth: rtbt_pci_probe(): PCI Dev(0000:02:00.1) get resource at 0xf7d00000,VA 0xffffa64041d80000,IRQ 17.
    [ 1965.556935] Bluetooth: call dev_ops->dev_ctrl_init!
    [ 1965.556951] Bluetooth: call dev_ops->dev_resource_init!
    [ 1965.582792] Bluetooth: RtmpOSIRQRequest(): request_irq (IRQ=17)done, isr_handler=0xffffffffc1274640!
    [ 1968.792846] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c52 tx timeout
    [ 1968.832504] Bluetooth: rtbt_hci_dev_flush(dev=0xffff8ea3907f4000)
    [ 1968.900515] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
    [ 1968.900525] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
    [ 1968.900534] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
    [ 1971.898810] Bluetooth: RtmpOSIRQRequest(): request_irq (IRQ=17)done, isr_handler=0xffffffffc1274640!
    [ 1975.160848] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c1a tx timeout
```

Comment: It is unclear what you want. Do you wont to make it discoverable? Then why you try to scan? Making the adapter discoverable means that it becomes scannable by OTHER devices.

Comment: Yeah you are correct @Pilot6 the in-built bluetooth adapter is not finding any device nor discovereble to any other device.

Comment: So what is the device? Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: Yes done @Pilot6

Comment: This device is poorly supported by Linux. It is a very old device. There are alot of questions with some solutions. Some work now, some don't You can search by your adapter `RT3290`

Comment: Yeah I have searched a tons of solutions and they didn't worked and came to know that there are many bugs but I am confused that which one is correct and how to fix them even if I identifyed it, can you help me something about it ?@Pilot6

Comment: add output of `dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`

Comment: Yes done @GopalS

Comment: I suggest you add what you tried and did not work (with the corresponding output you get, if appropriate).

Comment: I have given everything ,bluetoothctl command, in it the scan on command should find all discoverable devices but its giving an error , now which extra details should I give to you. Ok you suggest me that what info should I give. @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio

Answer (score 0):

try doing the same with Blueman

try : reinstalling the driver [How to install wifi driver Ralink RT3290](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545238/how-to-install-wifi-driver-ralink-rt3290)

also bluez is pretty old on ubuntu, compile bluez from source
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git

Comment: Am I supposed to try those commands given on the bottom or download something? @ShrirajHegde

Comment: search how to compile from source

Comment: Sorry but I don't know how to do that.@ShrirajHegde

Comment: search how to compile a program from source