# ubuntu 14.04 wifi "Device not ready"

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless

The wifi in my hp probook 4540s with ubuntu 14.04 not working with message "Device not ready"
I tried `$ rfkill list` that showed me

> phy0: Wireless LAN
>
> Soft blocked: no
>
> Hard blocked: no

I tried `rfkill unblock all` and rebooted but the problem is the same.

I tried solution in this [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1864392) but that made the wifi disappear from the list so i had to undo it.

Finally i opened from live CD ubuntu 14.04 and the wifi works so no hardware problems.

Edit: I followed that [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos) and the result is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/15686796/).

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: OK! i have updated the question

Comment: There are several questions about getting RT3290 Wireless to work: http://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working. Search, if you need more info.

Comment: I tried every thing in that link ... no thing works with me