# How to install Ralink 3290 Wireless Card Driver "correctly"?

Tags: drivers, tar, ralink

Let's start by saying I'm still a total noob to Linux, my problem is that I'm trying to install a driver for my Wireless Card and got an error while trying to install the driver by using the command `modprobe rt3290sta`, the error is this:

What I did is I untared the driver I downloaded from this guide 
[How do I get a Ralink RT3290 wireless card working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working)

http://www.mediafire.com/download/l3zoch2y1hbcali/RT3290.tar.gz

And after extracting I found out that the structure of the tar is not the same as in the guide so I extracted the src.tar.gz in the folder too and I stops at `modprobe rt3290sta`:

`modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rt3290sta': Operation not permitted`

The results are for other commands are as below:

`lspci -vnn | grep Network`

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe [1814:3290]
```

`iwconfig`

```
wlo1      IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

enx001e101f0000  no wireless extensions.

eno1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

I add that the WiFi appears correctly on the menu panel.

Pardon-me, English is not my native language and neither does code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use "sudo" with the modprobe command, like this:

sudo modprobe rt3290sta

...then enter your admin password (your password)

Cheers, Al

Comment: Please rate my answer by clicking on the up arrow shown in my answer. Thanks! Al

Comment: I accepted your answer :)
But the upper arrow just won't take my vote down... Sorry for my ignorance
**Thanks a lot a I appreciate it**