# How do I get a Ralink RT3290 wireless card working? I am stuck on step 6

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, kernel, ralink

[According this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working)

When i go to step 6 and run sudo make install then problem is occour which is shown below

```
make -C /home/dev/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux -f Makefile.6 install 

mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/etc/Wireless’: File exists 

make[1]: Entering directory `/home/dev/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux' 

rm -rf /etc/Wireless/RT2860STA

mkdir /etc/Wireless/RT2860STA 

cp /home/dev/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/RT2860STA.dat /etc/Wireless/RT2860STA/. 

install -d /lib/modules/4.2.0-42-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/

install -m 644 -c rt3290sta.ko /lib/modules/4.2.0-42-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ 

install: cannot stat ‘rt3290sta.ko’: No such file or directory 

make[1]: *** [install] Error 1 

make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/dev/Downloads/DPO_RT3290_LinuxSTA_V2600_20120508/os/linux'



make: *** [install] Error 2
```

[Wireless info script output](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23465144/)

Comment: Please run the script in [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425180#425180) and provide a [pastebin link](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) to the output. Thank you for helping us help you!

Comment: It is doubtful that you will get this antique from 2012 to compile or even work in a modern 4.2.0-xx kernel.

Comment: This is [the answer](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23454564/)  after running script which is provided by link @ElderGeek and Thanks for your reply. what next

Comment: My apologies for any confusion you may have experienced. Actually we need the results which based on the output you provided is saved in "/home/dev/wireless-info.txt"

Comment: Here is the [Wireless -info.txt](https://paste.ubuntu.com/23465144/) file @ElderGeek

Comment: Did you read the part of the answer you linked at the top of your post that says "if you have trouble compiling"? Did you try that?