# System gets started after shutdown - after upgrading Ubuntu from 14.04 to 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, shutdown, hp

I have upgraded my Kubuntu to 16.04. Ever since then, I cannot shutdown my session at once. When I choose the menu option, everything goes as expected at first. However, some 5 seconds after my HP Probook 4340s is turned off, it starts again as if the power button has been pressed again (and it was not).

The `laptop-mode-tools` installation has not helped, nor did grub settings' modifications ("`acpi=noirq`"/"`acpi=force`" and "`apm=power_off`"). The Wake-on-LAN setting in BIOS is also turned off.

When studying the `journalctl` log from shutdown and start procedures also did not show anything suspicious.

I do not think that the problem is related to hardware, since it had not occurred in previous versions of (K)Ubuntu.

Where could be the problem? What else shall I check?

Output of **`sudo lshw -sanitize`**:

```
computer
    description: Notebook
    product: HP ProBook 4340s (H5U94ES#BCM)
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    version: A1019D110B
    serial: [REMOVED]
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=103C_5336AN G=N L=BUS B=HP S=PRO sku=H5U94ES#BCM uuid=[REMOVED]
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 17F0
       vendor: Hewlett-Packard
       physical id: 0
       version: KBC Version 58.20
       serial: [REMOVED]
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Hewlett-Packard
          physical id: b
          version: 68IRR Ver. F.43
          date: 10/07/2013
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 5056KiB
          capabilities: pci pcmcia upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU 2020M @ 2.40GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 0
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: Intel(R) Pentium(R) CPU 2020M @ 2.40GHz
          serial: [REMOVED]
          slot: U3E1
          size: 2399MHz
          capacity: 4GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer xsave lahf_lm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase smep erms xsaveopt dtherm arat pln pts cpufreq
          configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=2
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 2
             slot: Unknown
             size: 32KiB
             capacity: 32KiB
             capabilities: internal write-through instruction
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 3
             slot: Unknown
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: internal write-through unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 4
             slot: Unknown
             size: 2MiB
             capacity: 2MiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-cache
          description: L1 cache
          physical id: 1
          slot: Unknown
          size: 32KiB
          capacity: 32KiB
          capabilities: internal write-through data
          configuration: level=1
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 5
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMMProject-Id-Version: lshwReport-Msgid-Bugs-To: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>POT-Creation-Date: 2009-10-08 14:02+0200PO-Revision-Date: 2012-02-05 00:26+0000Last-Translator: Andi Chandler <Unknown>Language-Team: English (United Kingdom) <en_GB@li.org>MIME-Version: 1.0Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bitX-Launchpad-Export-Date: 2016-06-27 17:08+0000X-Generator: Launchpad (build 18115) [empty]
             physical id: 0
             slot: Bottom-Slot 1(top)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1600 MHz (0,6 ns)
             product: HMT351S6EFR8A-PB
             vendor: Hynix/Hyundai
             physical id: 1
             serial: [REMOVED]
             slot: Bottom-Slot 2(under)
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1600MHz (0.6ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=ivb_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:31 memory:d0000000-d03fffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:d0919000-d09193ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0
                      description: Mouse
                      product: 2.4G Wireless Mouse
                      vendor: Genius
                      physical id: 2
                      bus info: usb@1:1.2
                      version: 1.00
                      capabilities: usb-1.10
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=50mA speed=12Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1
                      description: Video
                      product: HP HD Webcam [Fixed]
                      vendor: DDEJL01BI3P5J0
                      physical id: 3
                      bus info: usb@1:1.3
                      version: 24.02
                      capabilities: usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=uvcvideo maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:33 memory:d0910000-d0913fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: c4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:d0800000-d08fffff ioport:bf200000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: c4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25 ioport:5000(size=4096) memory:d0700000-d07fffff ioport:bf400000(size=2097152)
           *-generic:0
                description: System peripheral
                product: SD/MMC Host Controller
                vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                version: 30
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=sdhci-pci latency=0
                resources: irq:18 memory:d0703000-d07030ff memory:d0710000-d071ffff
           *-generic:1 UNCLAIMED
                description: SD Host controller
                product: Standard SD Host Controller
                vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
                physical id: 0.2
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.2
                version: 30
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:d0702000-d07020ff
           *-generic:2
                description: System peripheral
                product: MS Host Controller
                vendor: JMicron Technology Corp.
                physical id: 0.3
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.3
                version: 30
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
                configuration: driver=jmb38x_ms latency=0
                resources: irq:18 memory:d0701000-d07010ff
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.3
             version: c4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:26 ioport:6000(size=4096) memory:d0600000-d06fffff ioport:bf600000(size=2097152)
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
                vendor: Ralink corp.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 00
                serial: [REMOVED]
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.0-45-generic firmware=0.37 ip=[REMOVED] latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
                resources: irq:19 memory:d0610000-d061ffff
           *-generic UNCLAIMED
                description: Bluetooth
                product: RT3290 Bluetooth
                vendor: Ralink corp.
                physical id: 0.1
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.1
                version: 00
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:d0600000-d060ffff
        *-pci:3
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.5
             version: c4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:27 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:d0500000-d05fffff ioport:d0400000(size=1048576)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: eth0
                version: 07
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 1Gbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:29 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:d0918000-d09183ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=2 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: HM76 Express Chipset LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage msi pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:30 ioport:3068(size=8) ioport:3074(size=4) ioport:3060(size=8) ioport:3070(size=4) ioport:3040(size=32) memory:d0917000-d09177ff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:28 memory:d0900000-d090ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@4
                logical name: usb4
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=5000Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.4.0-45-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@3
                logical name: usb3
                version: 4.04
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=4 speed=480Mbit/s
        *-communication
             description: Communication controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:32 memory:d0914000-d091400f
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: KINGSTON SV300S3
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: BBF0
             serial: [REMOVED]
             size: 111GiB (120GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=45862143-dabb-42c0-8676-e46142550597 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /boot/efi
                version: FAT32
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 510MiB
                capacity: 511MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 107GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2016-01-02 20:08:37 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2016-12-16 16:01:22 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,commit=600,data=ordered mounted=2016-12-16 16:01:23 state=mounted
           *-volume:2
                description: Linux swap volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                version: 1
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 3975MiB
                capacity: 3975MiB
                capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 3
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: Hitachi HTS54505
             vendor: Hitachi
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             version: A7A0
             serial: [REMOVED]
             size: 465GiB (500GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=0452c726-09ff-44f5-9609-74448ff309e4 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=4096
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: mkfs.fat
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sdb1
                version: FAT32
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 510MiB
                capacity: 511MiB
                capabilities: boot fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=EFI System Partition
           *-volume:1
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sdb2
                version: 1.0
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 48GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2015-08-17 11:04:43 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2016-11-27 19:53:10 mounted=2016-11-27 13:25:58 state=clean
           *-volume:2
                description: Linux swap volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sdb3
                version: 1
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 3975MiB
                capacity: 3975MiB
                capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
           *-volume:3
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sdb4
                logical name: /media/michalzarnay/a819df4f-5352-4e68-a7e3-21d400af45a8
                version: 1.0
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 412GiB
                capabilities: journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink recover extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2016-01-03 20:56:34 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/media/michalzarnay/a819df4f-5352-4e68-a7e3-21d400af45a8 modified=2016-12-17 11:05:53 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,commit=600,data=ordered mounted=2016-12-17 11:05:53 state=mounted
  *-battery
       product: RC06051
       vendor: 11-85
       physical id: 1
       slot: Primary
       capacity: 50970mWh
       configuration: voltage=10,8V
```

Comment: From which release did you upgrade?

Comment: I think it was 14.04

Comment: One change which may affect, `upstart` replaced with `systemd` in 16.04. To check, on boot select advanced options then (upstart). see if it does shutdown correctly.

Comment: Did not help. I made 2 tries with upstart. One was successful (i.e. not automatic reboot) and one not. 
Before, in the default configuration, there were 2 times in a row that the automatic reboot has not appeared, but in all other cases (tens of tries since the last post), it keeps rebooting.
Where could be the non-determinism from?

Comment: Michal, Could you [edit] the question and add output of `sudo lshw -sanitize` , so we can compare with other cases . Also, have you tried `acpi=off` as explained https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI ?  `acpi=off` is to disable ACPI support completely. If we couldn't resolve it,  you have to go with bug report against linux kernel as explained in same page. Then add a link to the bug report so I can follow with you.

Comment: @user.dz, the output is added, hope it is ok in the external location.
The `acpi=off` was tested and it did not help: when turned on, the shutdown sequence stopped on the Kubuntu logo shining and the notebook did not turn off until I have pushed the on/off button. Some 5 seconds after, as usual, the automatic start has occurred again.
Can you please write me in what page to file the bug? The `ubuntu-bug` way does not seem to me to be the right way. I have the necessary report files ready.

Comment: Michal, Just run `ubuntu-bug linux` , it will collect additional info. then click send, it will open web browser on launchpad site. less then a minute it will ask you to fill the subject & description of the bug. Then upload those APCI related outputs. BTW, There is a newer BIOS firmware for this model released in May 2016 (current one is from 2013), project developers may ask you upgrade it, and also test last upstream kernel.

Comment: @user.dz, can you please direct me to the BIOS firmware upgrade? I am not able to find it (HP website checked).

Comment: Yeah sure, here [the support page](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/readIndex?sp4ts.oid=5229481&swLangOid=8&swEnvOid=1093) and direct link to firmware [F.62 Rev.A(8 Nov 2016)](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/swd/public/detail?sp4ts.oid=5229481&swItemId=ob_177208_1&swEnvOid=1093#tab1)

Comment: @user.dz, sorry, to play with your patience... I am trying to install the firmware according to the instructions in [link](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Operating-System-and-Recovery/How-to-update-BIOS-on-Linux/td-p/4869835), but the only BIN file in the package, I found the Rom.bin from ROM.CAB. Is that the right one? I doubt... Or is there something missing?

Comment: You are welcome, no problem. Yes that the right file ~5MB , I'm not sure how did you extract it, but I could find all needed files as explained in the instructions. I'm used `file-roller` in 16.04 and got these files https://paste.ubuntu.com/23670363/

Comment: @user.dz, I managed to move on slightly. While still removing obstacles on updating the BIOS, I have a new observation to share: when I turn off the wireless network device before shutting down, the automatic restart does not happen. I tried it a few times, it works as a rule. So, the problem of automatic restart instead of shutdown must be connected to the wireless network adapter. Any idea on that?

Comment: After your last comment, I searched about similar cases, this seems a common case with ralink wireless driver `rt2800pci` .  I could find only workarounds like switching off wifi on with shutdown process as in  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296823/12209 , some other answers in AU suggest installing modiffied `rt*sta` DKMS driver and blacklist `rt*pci` from kernel package, method explained in https://askubuntu.com/a/253660/26246 .

Comment: However, I'm in doubt why this happens for some users after upgrade, some regression in Ubuntu in how to deal with such device.  Even these workaround may work, I still recommend filing a complete report about this, (still related to `linux` package). I couldn't find any bug report about this issue, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux?field.searchtext=ralink&search=Search