# Wireless interface disabled

Tags: wireless

I am new to ubuntu and I have faced some problems with my wifi connections. My laptop doesn't see it.

```
sudo lshw -C network
*-network DISABLED
     description: Wireless interface
```

...

```
*-network
     description: Ethernet interface
```

And

```
rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Also i did

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo reboot
```

My card is ralink 3290 and ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS. 
I will be very grateful for your responses

Comment: What's the output of **lspci | grep -i net** ?

Comment: Maybe you can check this guide http://askubuntu.com/questions/253632/how-do-i-get-a-ralink-rt3290-wireless-card-working